# How can I concatenate a shell variable to other other parameters in my command lines ?

Tags: shell-script, shell, variable

How can I concatenate a shell variable to other other parameters in my command lines?

For example,

```
#!/bin/sh
WEBSITE="danydiop" 
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root --ppassword $WEBSITE > $WEBSITE.sql
```

I need to concatenate `.sql` to `$WEBSITE`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `${ }` to enclosure a variable.

Without curly brackets:

```
VAR="foo"
echo $VAR
echo $VARbar
```

would give

```
foo
```

and nothing, because the variable `$VARbar` doesn't exist.

With curly brackets:

```
VAR="foo"
echo ${VAR}
echo ${VAR}bar
```

would give

```
foo
foobar
```

Enclosing the first `$VAR` is not necessary, but a good practice.

For your example:

```
#!/bin/sh
WEBSITE="danydiop" 
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root --ppassword ${WEBSITE} > ${WEBSITE}.sql
```

This works for `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, maybe others too.

Comment: This works for all Bourne-style shells (Bourne, POSIX, bash, ksh, zsh), C-style shells (csh, tcsh), and even in fish without the braces. So it's really universal amongst unix shells. I wouldn't call the braces good practice. But I do call systematically using double quotes around variable substitutions good practice.

Comment: @Gilles, I'd go further and say than _not_ using double quotes around variable substitutions is [very](/q/171346) **bad** practice.

Comment: Also, take care that `${ }` is not concatenation in any sense. For example, `ELP=elp && echo $ELP && man --h${EPL}` does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Just concatenate the variable contents to whatever else you want to concatenate, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root --ppassword "$WEBSITE" > "$WEBSITE.sql"
```

The double quotes are unrelated to concatenation: here `>$WEBSITE.sql` would have worked too. They are needed around variable expansions when the value of the variable might contain some shell special characters (whitespace and `\[?*`). I strongly recommend putting double quotes around all variable expansions and command substitutions, i.e., always write `"$WEBSITE"` and `"$(mycommand)"`.

For more details, see [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote).

Answer (score 2):

I usually use quotes, e.g. `echo "$WEBSITE.sql"`.

So you could write it like:

```
#!/bin/sh
WEBSITE="danydiop" 
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root --ppassword $WEBSITE > "$WEBSITE.sql"
```

Comment: This does work since `.` isn't a valid character in a variable name; see [wag's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5389/how-can-i-concatenate-a-shell-variable-to-other-other-parameters-in-my-command-li/5391#5391) if you want to concatenate a string that does start with valid characters (e.g. "$WEBSITEsql" wouldn't work)