# How to test if a file starting with a particular prefix is present in a directory in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I need to test if a file starting with "ant" is present in the directory. If that is present, I need to delete that file. The command that I am using now is

```
test -e $FILE_PATH/$FILE_NAME
```

I have defined

```
FILE_NAME="ant"
```

Putting * after the FILE_NAME is not working out.

Comment: Try using find. Use -exec to remove the file if found.

Comment: have you considered just doing: `rm -f "${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME}"*`? Then the file(s) are gone either way!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate a shell variable to other other parameters in my command lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5389/how-can-i-concatenate-a-shell-variable-to-other-other-parameters-in-my-command-l)

Comment: If both of those vars are empty you will match root...

Comment: What do you want to have happen if there are two files that start with "ant" ?

Comment: It doesn't work in what way exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One portable way to remove such a file if only one exists:

```
set -- "${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME}"*
[ $# -eq 1 -a -e "$1" ] && rm -- "$1"
```

It seems to me that if you don't care how many of these 'ant' files exist beforehand, but want them (all) gone when you're done, just:

```
rm -f "${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME}"*
```

-- that way, if there were no such files, rm will (forced-quiet) not doing anything, but if there were (any -- 1 or more!) such files, `rm` will remove them.

Comment: In POSIX shells, `set -- "${FILE_PATH}/${FILE_NAME}"*`, will also set $# to 1 if there's no matching file as then the pattern is passed literally instead of the matching files.

Comment: excellent catch; thank you, @StéphaneChazelas. I've updated the answer to additionally check for the existence of $1 and also safeguarded the "rm" with a -- delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this:

```
-sh-4.1$ dir=$(pwd)  ; filename="ant" 

if (( $(shopt -s nullglob; set -- ${dir}/${filename}*;  echo $#) > 0 ));  then rm
${dir}/${filename}* ; fi
```

`shopt -s nullglob` : will ensure noting is returned if the directory is empty.

`set -- ${dir}/${filename}* :` sets the positional param.

`$#` : returns the count of positional params. as the condition for excuting rm

as a one linear :

```
1$ dir=$(pwd) ; filename="ant" ;  if (( $(shopt -s nullglob; set -- ${dir}/${filename}*;  echo $#) > 0 )); then rm     ${dir}/${filename}* ; fi
```