# How to test if one or more files with a prefix exists in bash? e.g. [[-f foo*]]

Tags: bash, filenames, test

Is there a way to use a [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) within a [`test` expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), more specifically, a [bash conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)?

For example:

```
[[ -f foo* ]] && echo 'found it!' || echo 'nope!';
```

... will output *"nope!"* either if the `foobar` file exists on the current directory or not.

And adding a `var` like...

```
bar=foo*
[[ -f `echo $bar` ]] && echo 'found it!' || echo 'nope!';
```

... will output *"found it!"* if the `foobar` file exists, but only if the `echo $bar` expansion returned only one file.

Comment: related and useful entries [make-mv-fail-silently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87605/is-there-a-way-to-make-mv-fail-silently) and [how-to-test-if-a-file-starting-with-a-particular-prefix-is-present-in-a-director](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298653/how-to-test-if-a-file-starting-with-a-particular-prefix-is-present-in-a-director)

Comment: use `find` command.

Comment: What would the semantics of `-f foo*` be? Should it be true if all names that matches `foo*` are regular files, or should it be true if some of the names matching `foo*` are regular files?  Note that it would be easier to define this for `-e foo*`, which is not what you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The following assume that you don't care whether the glob matches any files, including block special files, character special files, directories, symlinks, etc.

This is the ideal use case for `failglob`:

```
shopt -s failglob
if echo foo* &>/dev/null
then
    # files found
else
    # no files found
fi
```

Or, if you need the list of files if they exist:

```
shopt -s failglob
files=(foo*)
if [[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]
then
    # no files found
else
    # files found
fi
```

If no files found is an error you could simplify this:

```
set -o errexit
shopt -s failglob
files=(foo*)
# We know that the expansion succeeded if we reach this line
```

---

### Old answer

This might be a (rare!) legitimate use of `ls` in a script:

```
if ls foo* &>/dev/null
then
    …
else
    …
fi
```

Alternatively, `find foo* -maxdepth 0 -printf ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87610/98982), we can use `shopt -s nullglob` to ensure noting is returned if the directory is empty:

```
[[ -n "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo foo*)" ]] && echo 'found it!' || echo 'nope!';
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `&&` and `||`, just use an if construct, it's also not necessary to terminate the line with `;`

Comment: This does not seem to capture the fact that the question uses `-f` and not `-e` as the test operator. The test should be for regular files, not for existence.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, here are some examples using `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash

term=$1

if find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$term*" -print -quit | grep -q .; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi

if [ -n "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$term*" -print -quit)" ]; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

And some tests:

```
user@host > find -type f
./foobar
./bar/foo
./bar/bar
./find_prefixed_files.sh
./ba
user@host > ./find_prefixed_files.sh foo
found
found
user@host > ./find_prefixed_files.sh bar
not found
not found
```