# Creating an empty file having a variable name in a script

Tags: shell-script, files, quoting

I need to create an empty file using a shell script. The filename will be determined by examining all the files in a directory matching a pattern, say `TEST.*`, and appending `_END` to it so that the new file might look like `TEST.2011_END`.  Let the current directory be `$DIR`. So I tried:

```
for file in $DIR/TEST.*
do
    touch $file_END  
done
```

This gives an error. I also tried replacing `touch $file_END` with:

```
filename=$file_END  
touch $filename
```

but with no luck. What should I do?

Comment: `touch` is often used to create an *empty* file, but its primary purpose it to *touch* a file's *timestamp*... If a file with the name already exist, 'touch' will not make it become "empty".... If you want to force an existing file to be **empty** (thereby losing any data it contains), you can use `cp /dev/null "${file}_END"` which will either create an empty file if it doesn't currently exist, or if it does exist, it will truncate it to zero length (ie. empty)...

Comment: @fred.bear: A common idiom to create or truncate a file is `: >"${file}_END"`

Comment: See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
filename="${file}_END"
```

or in your code

```
touch "${file}_END"
```

The `"` quotes are not necessary as long as `$file` does not have any whitespace or globbing character in it.

Comment: Always put double quotes around variable substitutions unless you know you need field splitting and pathname expansion. This is a simpler and safer approach than trying to figure out whether they are strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

the command interpreter thinks you mean $file_END ( value of the variable named file_END ). you can work around this by quoting.
The syntax could be:

```
filename="$file""_END"
```

or

```
filename="$file"_END
```

or even

```
filename=$file"_END"
```

though i prefer the first one for clarity!

Comment: I consider `"${file}_END"` more clear still.