# What's the quickest way to add text to a file from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

Occasionally I have a thought that I want to write into a file while I am at the terminal.  I would want these notes all in the same file, just listed one after the other.  I would also like a date / time tag on each one.

Is it possible to do this without having to open the file each time?  Can I just enter it into the terminal and have it appended to the file each time with a command or script?

I am using GNU BASH.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Write yourself a shell script called "n".  Put this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
notefile=/home/me/notefile
date >> $notefile
emacs $notefile -f end-of-buffer
```

I recommend this instead of `cat >> notefile` because:

1. One day you'll be in such a hurry that you'll fumblefinger the >> and type > instead and blow away your file.
2. Emacs starts in *five one-hundredths of a second* on my Mac Mini.  It takes a tenth of a second to start on a ten year old Celeron-based system I have sitting around.  If you can't wait that long to start typing, then you're already a machine and don't need to take notes. :)

If you insist on avoiding a text editor, use a shell function:

```
n () { date >> /home/me/notefile; cat >> /home/me/notefile; }
```

which should work in all shells claiming Bourne shell compatibility.

Comment: How does the `n` function write to the file? Don't you mean something like a `echo "$*"` rather than [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)? How does it incorporate the date/time tag?

Comment: Not quite useless.  It reads from stdin, which is  where the user will be typing their note.  I did forget the datestamp, though.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree about the UUOC, but you have you point back for the date...

Comment: +1 nice defensive coding *and* rationale against the inevitable typo.

Comment: Kyle, you obviously don't have a 90MB `.emacs.d`. Yikes, I need to clean that up.

Comment: Esepcially good because it doesn't force neophytes to memorize that >> means append, because if they had to type that in over and over, soon the day would come when they typed > instead. Oops!

Answer (score 36):

Also, to write multiple lines to a file from the command line, do:

```
cat >> sometextfile.txt << EOF
text
more text
and another line
EOF
```

Comment: Or `cat > sometextfile.txt << EOF` to overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 23):

Just use `echo`:

```
echo $(date) Hi. >> notes.txt
```

You can use >> to append to a file, or use > to overwrite it.

Comment: thank you, echo is what i needed

Answer (score 3):

Lots of neat bells and whistles here!

KISS method:

```
date >>filename; cat >>filename
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have ruby installed on your computer you can use https://github.com/minhajuddin/taskr . This way you get a nice view of your notes with tags and the hours elapsed.

[image: Taskr screenshot]

Comment: Well, screenshots look often very well, but if you can, it is much better if you use copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "`date` text here" >> filename
```

or

```
echo "text here `date`"|tee -a filename
```

more on [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29)

Comment: single backtick only

Comment: For what it's worth, I would recommend using `$(..)` over the backticks for command substitution. More info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/why-the-double-quotes-and-backquotes-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, syslogd might be another tool to peruse. The command

```
theuser@tetrad:~$ logger This message is sent to syslog
```

will log the message with the facility user.notice. With many Linux systems this will be enough to have a file /var/log/user.log opened and appended to, with others you may need to define a handling for that facility and log level (or, whichever facility you choose - the local0 to local7 facilities are usually free to assign to things like this.

It's got the benefit of being able (aka configurable) to send notes from client machines to a central logging server, something I like to use for keeping track of administrative action since it preserves timestamp, user and host information automagically, while keeping actions in order.

resulting output in local file:

```
theuser@tetrad:~$ tail /var/log/user.log
Jan 31 07:18:37 tetrad theuser: This message is sent to syslog
```

Example for syslog configuration line on **Solaris**:

```
local5.notice             ifdef(`LOGHOST', /var/log/diary, @loghost)
```

Note: The `ifdef` is preprocessed with `m4`, on the machine with the hostname/hostalias "loghost", the messages will be logged to the file /var/log/diary, on all others, they will be sent to the remote syslog service at loghost. To test this kind of configuration, the config file can be sent through m4 for expansion (leave away the `-D LOGHOST` to see how it would look on a system not called *loghost*:

```
theuser@solstice$ /usr/ccs/bin/m4 -D LOGHOST /etc/syslog.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

[Taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/show/taskwarrior) may do what you wanted a little better than a simple shell script. The [30-second Tutorial](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/taskwarrior/wiki/30-second_Tutorial) should tell you if I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Combining a few different answers to achieve what I sought out, which was multiple options.

1. Quick

   ```
   user@hostname:~/Documents$ echo text >> filename
   user@hostname:~/Documents$ cat filename
   text
   ```
2. Multiple Lines

  ```
  user@hostname:~/Documents$ cat >> filename2 << EOF
  > text line 1
  > text line 2
  > text line 3
  > EOF
  user@hostname:~/Documents$ cat filename2  
  text line 1
  text line 2
  text line 3
  ```

3. Modify a file at a given line number

   ```
   user@hostname:~/Documents$ sed -i '2iinserting new line' filename2
   user@hostname:~/Documents$ cat filename2
   text line 1
   inserting new line
   text line 2
   text line 3
   ```

   - Credit 1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30128/145311
   - Credit 2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44143/145311
   - Credit 3. https://askubuntu.com/a/435309/192800