# Bash, curious about echo $variable

Tags: bash, quoting

I was hacking at a small script earlier and noticed something I can't explain.

Running this command

```
(time wget --spider http://www.google.co.uk/) 2>&1  | egrep 'real|response'
```

gives me this output (which I expect)

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
real    0m0.086s
```

I capture the output above in a variable

```
Result=$((time wget --spider http://www.google.co.uk/) 2>&1  | egrep 'real|response')
```

If I

```
echo "$Result"
```

I get the expected output

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
real    0m0.086s
```

However if I

```
echo $Result
```

I get

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK real    0m0.086s
```

Why is that ?

Comment: See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Comment: By the way, you probably want `wget -q` here, if you haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `echo $Result` command will convert the value of the variable into multiple arguments for echo, splitting on any whitespace, and echo prints all the arguments separated by spaces. On the other hand, `echo "$Result"` will put the whole string, including whitespace, into the first and only echo argument, which gets printed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Adam's answer pointed me in the right direction in that it is related to whitespace. More specifically the `\n` between the two lines is interpreted as whitespace and is converted to a single , when using `$Result` but is left as `\n` when using `"$Result"`.

I'd never really considered '\n' to be whitespace before.

Comment: The variable $IFS (Internal Field Seperator) governs what is classed as whitespace.. eg. `echo -n "$IFS" | xxd -p` ... returns `20090a` ... space, tab, newline   (`xxd` is a hex dump utility packaged with vim)