# Concatenate multiple strings with spaces in them?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh

I am trying to do the following in ksh shell:

```
JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation

SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION="$JMX_ROOT/\"Smoke Set\"/*.txt $JMX_ROOT/\"Smoke Set\"/*.TXT 
$JMX_ROOT/\"Smoke Set\"/SmokeSet.jmx"

cp $SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION /var/tmp
```

I.e. copy .txt, .TXT and .jmx files from one directory to another directory but am getting errors because of the spaces in "Smoke Set".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions** (`$foo` and `$(cmd)`), unless you understand why not to do it in a particular case (start [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899) or [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)). So: start with `cp "$SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION" /var/tmp`, whereupon you realize that you have a single first argument to `cp`. Then think carefully about what omitting the quotes would do, and you get [l0b0's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23390#23390). (Note the double quotes in `"${SMOKE_JMX_LOCATIONS[@]}"`, too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally can't put several paths in a single string, because *anything** which is a valid string is also a valid path in most file systems. You could use an array:

```
JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation
set -A SMOKE_JMX_LOCATIONS "$JMX_ROOT/Smoke Set/"*.txt "$JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/"*.TXT "$JMX_ROOT/Smoke Set/SmokeSet.jmx"
cp "${SMOKE_JMX_LOCATIONS[@]}" /var/tmp
```

* Before anyone protests about `\0` and `/`, the former can't be part of a variable (at least if ksh works like [Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006); couldn't find a reference), and the latter can't be part of *file names*, but it's very much valid in *paths*.

Comment: Zsh is the only shell that I recall coping with null characters.