# Bind locally installed library

Tags: linux, compiling, autoconf

I have no root access on a machine and I'm trying to install a library called GiNaC locally in my home folder.

I use this tutorial http://www.ginac.de/tutorial/Configuration.html#Configuration. At the end there is an example (don't need to disable the shared-library and I don't need a specific compiler).

Unfortunately if I do this

```
export CPPFLAGS="$(CPPFLAGS) -I$/home/xxx/include"
./configure
```

this is the result:

```
...
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/redies/ginac-1.6.2':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

In config.log there is the line

```
CPPFLAGS='CPPFLAGS: command not found -I$/home/xxx/include'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in that tutorial: in the shell, variable expansions use braces, not parentheses, so you need to write `${CPPFLAGS}` and not `$(CPPFLAGS)`. You can [leave the braces off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote), even. Also, if you replace `$HOME` by its value, the `$` must go (`$` followed by a variable name means “take the value of”).

```
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/home/xxx/include"
```

Oh, and if there's no prior value of `CPPFLAGS` in your environment, you can write this `export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/xxx/include"` (but it won't hurt to use `$CPPFLAGS` either, the value is empty if the variable has never been set).

Answer (score 0):

I think that unless you've got extra CPPFLAGS values, this one would work;

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/xxx/include" ./configure
```

I also think you should run `./configure --help` to see if this particular configure-script has command line flags to do what you want.  The usual configure-script has piles of options to allow J. Random Non-root-user to install in in $HOME, or whatever.