# What is the difference between $var and "$var"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

I assigned a variable var a value as follows:

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ var="Pradeep
> is     
> a good
> boy"
```

Then I issued a echo command as:

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ echo $var
Pradeep is a good boy
```

and for the command:

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ echo "$var"
Pradeep
is 
a good
boy
```

I want to know why there is difference in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expansions that occur within double quotes (`"`) do not undergo [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).

---

In `echo $var`, since the expansion of `$var` does not occur within double-quotes, so it does undergo splitting.  The shell runs `echo` with the 5 arguments: `Pradeep`, `is`, `a`, `good`, `boy`.  `echo` prints all of its arguments separated with a space.

In `echo "$var"`, the expansion of `$var` occurs within double-quotes, so it does not undergo splitting.  The shell runs `echo` with a single argument,

```
Pradeep
is
a good
boy
```

which `echo` faithfully prints.