# How to move file from one folder to another in shell script by changing the permission

Tags: shell, quoting

I want to move a file from one folder to another folder.

When the file's format is with space in between (`file _name.dat`) and when I am using the command `mv file _name.dat /tmp`  then the file is not moving.

But when am using `mv "file _name.dat" /tmp` then the file is moving.

Help me in writing a script which helps to change the `file _name.dat` to `"file _name.dat"` when it is moving automatically.

Comment: It's not clear to me what to you want to do. Do you want to type `mv file _name.dat /tmp` and have it execute `mv "file _name.dat" /tmp` instead?

Comment: Recommended reading: [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very hard to understand. In particular, you need to **copy-paste your code** and **copy-paste error messages**.

That being said, there's a good chance that you made a classic mistake…

---

When a shell script contains a variable substitution (something like `$file` or `$1`), the result of the expansion is treated as a whitespace-separated sequence of wildcard patterns. The variable is not treated as a single word, but as a list of patterns. So if you write

```
mv $1 /tmp      # <<<< BAD
```

and you run `myscript "file _name.dat"`, then the `mv` command receives three arguments: `file`, `_name.dat` and `/tmp`. If you run `myscript "*.dat"`, then all the `.dat` files in the current directory are moved.

To avoid this, put the variable substitution between double quotes: `mv "$1" /tmp`. If you do this, `mv` always receives exactly two arguments: the first argument of the script, and `/tmp`. It is extremely rare to need to treat variables' values as lists of wildcard patterns, so remember this simple rule:

> **Always put double quotes around variable substitutions**: `"$foo"`, `"$1"`, etc. This also goes for command substitutions: `"$(mycommand)"`

Furthermore, in case the file name begins with a dash (`-`), `mv` would treat it as an option. To avoid this, pass `--` to mark the end of the options: anything after `--` is a non-option argument (a file or directory name, for `mv`). Most commands recognize `--` to mark the end of options.

```
mv -- "$1" /tmp
```

---

If you wanted to invoke your script by writing `myscript file _name.dat /tmp` in a shell, that is not possible. The script receives the arguments separately, it doesn't know how many spaces you happened to type on the command line. (This is different from Windows, where a program parses its own arguments. On unix, programs receive a list of arguments.) If you call your script from another shell script, use proper quoting in the calling script as well.