# $(tail) into variable removing \n

Tags: bash, email, tail

I am doing the following:

```
x="Hello to the world of tomorrow\n <pre>";
x="${x}$(tail -n 50 log/logfile.log)"
x="${x}</pre>";
echo -e $x | ./perlscript
```

The Perl script:

```
#!perl
# perlscript
open(MAIL, "sendmail -t")
print MAIL "EMAIL HEADERS\n\n"
print MAIL <STDIN>
close(MAIL);
```

When I receive the email, the log file doesn't have any `\n` inside the `<pre>` tag. The `Hello to the world of tomorrow` works fine and the `\n` is represented.

How to I get `tail` not to remove any `\n`, or is it something further down/up the chain?

Comment: Is the first code block a bashscript or something, or are you just typing it on the command line?

Comment: Do you actually want `\n` (2 characters) or a newline character?  Keep in mind `echo` is very nonportable when it comes to handling backslashes.  If you want predictable behavior use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Yes i Want the `\n`, and its a bashscript, but could be command line

Comment: Sorry the `echo` should be `echo -e`

Comment: @whoami No, saying you want `echo -e \n` probably means you *really* want an actual newline, and `echo -e \n` is your attempt at getting one.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but why are you embedding what looks to be HTML tags into a plain text email?  That is not good form.

Comment: @jw013 - Its not plain text, `print MAIL "EMAIL HEADERS\n\n"` was an abbreviation for HTML content type header, and all the to: from: subject: fields. Sorry was lazy to type :D

Comment: Oh ok, never mind then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

double quotes are missing in the command echo :

```
echo -e "$x" | ./perlscript
```

Comment: Thats the one....Would be nice to understand why the differnce between `echo -e "$x"` and `echo -e $x`

Comment: @whoami, look in the shell man page for "word splitting" -- when you don't quote the variable, all sequences of whitespace are replaced by a single space.

Comment: I don't think this is the only problem. I think that `$(...)` constructs also drop the trailing space. Witness that `A=$(printf "abc\n"); printf "<%s>" "$A"` will produce `<abc>`.

Comment: I agree but this error had to be identified

Comment: @whoami Always use double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: `"$x"`, `"$(somecommand)"`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020,[$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899)

Answer (score 5):

This is a much cleaner and more idiomatic way to go about what you are trying to do:

```
{ printf 'Hello to the world of tomorrow\n <pre>\n'
  tail -n 50 log/logfile.log
  printf '</pre>\n'; } | ./perlscript
```

There is no reason you need to buffer all that output in a variable first when you are just going to push it in order into the pipe anyways.