# bash script disapearing variable

Tags: bash

I have created a small script to move video files from a helmet mounted camera to my mythbuntu machine and there is a variable that for some reason will just not be passed onto the script. The variable in question is

```
d=`echo $file | awk '{ print $6 }'`
```

which is captured OK, however in the statement

```
scp -l 5000 $name $SavePath$d_$hour.AVI
```

will just not insert a value.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script does copy files from /media/disk/DCIM/100DSCIM to 
# 192.20.0.200:/media/Elements/mythtv/videos/BikeRiding and renames the files using the time stamp
set -x
SavePath=root@198.20.0.200:/media/Elements/mythtv/videos/BikeRiding/
SourcePath=/media/disk/DCIM/100DSCIM/
ls $SourcePath*.AVI --full-time > file_list
cat file_list | while read file
do
    d=`echo $file | awk '{ print $6 }'`
    hour=`echo $file | awk '{ print $7 }'`
    name=`echo $file | awk '{ print $9 }'`
    scp -l 5000 $name $SavePath$d_$hour.AVI
done
```

Comment: See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Answer (score 13):

This is because bash interprets variable name as `d_`. Use curly braces to border variable name in that case:

```
scp -l 5000 $name $SavePath${d}_$hour.AVI
```

or even

```
scp -l 5000 ${name} ${SavePath}${d}_${hour}.AVI
```

and it's much better to double quote variable to prevent error with name with strange symbols like space:

```
scp -l 5000 "${name}" "${SavePath}${d}_${hour}.AVI"
```

Comment: This answer is exactly right. But I wish I had a nickel for every time I've seen scripts using `${...}` where it wasn't needed, most often in the apparent belief that `${foo}` worked like `"$foo"`.