# Outputting last modification date to another file?

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, date

I'm trying to read the number of lines in a file, and the last modification date of that file (e.g. if it was last modified Jan 18, 2013, it should output `2013-01-18`), then append the data to the given input file in the form `theFile: 4 lines, modified on 2013-01-18`.  I tried to store both pieces of data in their own variables before outputting with echo.

```
#!/bin/sh
totLines=$(wc -l < $1)
modDate=$(date -r $1)
echo $1: $totLines "lines, modified on" $modDate >> $1
```

Is my method of finding the last modification date correct?  I was told that it is, but I can't figure out why, since I can't find any information on what `date -r` does and I can't get it working in any script I try out.  There's also using stat, but I can't get that working either with `stat -c %y $1` where I get `stat: illegal option -- c`

Answer (score 3):

Both `date -r` and this flavour of `stat` are GNU specific. Maybe you were told them by a Linux user and you're using another system.

Unfortunately, there's no standard command to get that information reliably. The most portable you could get would be:

```
modDate=$(perl -MPOSIX -le '@s=stat shift or die$!;
  print strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime $s[9]' -- "$1") || exit
```

`zsh` has its own builtin `stat` command:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
zstat -F %F +mtime -- "$1"
```

(those two commands above, for symlinks, would return the modification time of the target of the symlink like GNU `date -r` would, if you want the time of the symlink (like in you GNU `stat` command), change `stat` to `lstat` in the `perl` solution, or add `-L` to `zstat`).

Also, [you forgot the double quotes around your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote/4910#4910) and you shouldn't use `echo` for arbitrary data.

Comment: i agree, in `FreeBSD`, `stat -x` equal with `stat` in `linux`.