# Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, assignment

Can I safely omit quotes on the right side of a local assignment?

```
function foo {
    local myvar=${bar}
    stuff()
}
```

I'm mainly interested in `bash`, but any info on corner cases in other shells are welcome.

Comment: I think it makes no difference if it is on one line like you have it in your function. Assignments do not need quoting. See https://www.mpi-sb.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Quotes are needed in `export foo="$var"` or `local foo="$var"` (or `readonly`, `typeset`, `declare` and other variable declaring *commands*) in:

- `dash` versions 0.3.8-15 to 0.5.10.2 (see [change](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/dash/-/commit/cbb71a836874d176809a34e22f6b6e4e3ba8c85b)).
- the `sh` of NetBSD (also based on the Almquist shell).
- The `sh` of FreeBSD 9.2 or older (see the [change in 9.3](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=264423))
- [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en)
- `zsh` with versions prior to 5.1 in `ksh` or `sh` emulation (or for `export var="$(cmd)"` where `zsh` would  perform word splitting otherwise (not globbing)).

As otherwise the variable expansion would be subject to word splitting and/or filename generation like in any argument to any other command.

And are not needed in:

- `bash`
- `ksh` (all implementations)
- the `sh` of FreeBSD 9.3 or newer
- busybox' ash-based `sh` (since 2005)
- `zsh`
- `dash` 0.5.11 or newer.

In `zsh`, split+glob is never done upon parameter expansion, unless in `sh` or `ksh` emulation, but split (not glob) is done upon command substitution. Since version 5.1, `export`/`local` and other declaration commands have become dual *keyword*/*builtin* commands like in the other shells above, which means quoting is not necessary, even in `sh`/`ksh` emulation and even for command substitution.

There are special cases where quoting is needed even in those shells though like:

```
a="b=some value"
export "$a"
```

Or more generally, if anything left of the `=` (including the `=`) is quoted or the result of some expansion (like `export 'foo'="$var"`, `export foo\="$var"` or `export foo$((n+=1))="$var"` (that `$((...))` should also be quoted actually)...). Or in other words when the argument to `export` wouldn't be a valid variable assignment if written without the `export`.

If the `export`/`local` command name itself is quoted (even in part like `"export" a="$b"`, `'ex'port a="$b"`, `\export a="$b"`, or even `""export a="$b"`), the quotes around `$b` are needed except in AT&T `ksh`, `mksh` and recent versions of `dash`.

If `export`/`local` or some part of it is the result of some expansion (like in `cmd=export; "$cmd" a="$b"` or even `export$(:) a="$b"`) or in things like `dryrun=; $dryrun export a="$b"`), then the quotes are needed except in recent versions of `dash`.

In the case of `> /dev/null export a="$b"`, the quotes are needed in `pdksh` and some of its derivatives.

For `command export a="$b"`, the quotes are needed in every shell but `mksh`, `ksh93`, recent `dash`, and `bash -o posix` (with the same caveats about `command` and `export` not being the result of some expansion in shells other than `dash`).

They are not needed in any shell when written:

```
foo=$var export foo
```

(that syntax being also compatible with the Bourne shell but in recent versions of `zsh`, only working when in `sh`/`ksh` emulation).

(note that `var=value local var` shouldn't be used as the behaviour varies across shells).

Also note that using `export` with an assignment also means that the exit status of `cmd` in `export var="$(cmd)"` is lost. Doing it as `export var; var=$(cmd)` doesn't have that problem.

Also beware of this special case with `bash`:

```
$ bash -c 'IFS=; export a="$*"; echo "$a"' bash a b
ab
$ bash -c 'IFS=; export a=$*; echo "$a"' bash a b
a b
```

My advice would be to always quote.

Comment: Note that in `zsh` quotes _are_ needed for `local foo="$(cmd)"` because wordsplitting (but not filename generation) _is_ performed for unquoted command substitutions (but not for unquoted parameter expansions), unless `KSH_TYPESET` is enabled, in which case quotes _aren't_ needed. Make sense? No? Then always quote everything unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Matt, I love your conclusion.  :D  It's funny, most of what I've learned of shell scripting came from this stackexchange, so that I didn't realize that **always quote your variables** is *not* common knowledge amongst script writers.  I'm finding I have a lot of fixing up to do of existing production scripts written by people who *didn't* quote, and *didn't* know exactly what they were doing....

Comment: I don't think that `dash` actually need quoting on assignment:

 `$ echo $SHELL; FOO="foo bar"; BAR=$FOO; echo $BAR; f () { local BAZ="baz quux"; local QUUX=$BAZ; echo $QUUX; }; f` yields `/bin/dash`, `foo bar`, and `baz quux`

Comment: Thanks @EmanueleAina. It looks like it changed recently. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

I generally quote any usage of variables where there might be characters such as white spaces. Otherwise you'll run into problems like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

bar="hi bye"

function foo {
  local myvar=${bar}
  printf "%s\n" $myvar
  printf "%s\n" "$myvar"
}

foo
```

The usage of the variable in an assignment doesn't appear to need the quotes, but when you go to use it such as in the `printf` you'll need it quoted there:

```
  printf "%s\n" "$myvar"
```

**NOTE:** Remember that the variable `$IFS` is what governs what the separator characters are.

```
IFS    The  Internal  Field  Separator that is used for word splitting after 
       expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command. 
       The default value is ``<space><tab><newline>''.
```

#### Example

With debugging enabled in Bash we can see what's happening behind the scenes.

```
$ bash -x cmd.bash 
+ bar='hi bye'
+ foo
+ local 'myvar=hi bye'
+ printf '%s\n' hi bye
hi
bye
+ printf '%s\n' 'hi bye'
hi bye
```

In the above we can see that the variable, `$bar` was handed off fine to `$myvar` but then when we went to use `$myvar` we had to be cognoscente of the contents of `$myvar` when we went to use it.

Comment: word splitting is not the only problem with unquoted variables, you have to consider filename generation (aka globbing) as well (though that (both) doesn't apply in variable assignments and for `bash` and `ksh` in `local`/`typeset`... special builtins).