# Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

In my Bash environment I use variables containing spaces, and I use these variables within command substitution.

What is the correct way to quote my variables? And how should I do it if these are nested?

```sh
DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILE")
```

or do I quote outside the substitution?

```sh
DIRNAME="$(dirname $FILE)"
```

or both?

```sh
DIRNAME="$(dirname "$FILE")"
```

or do I use back-ticks?

```sh
DIRNAME=`dirname "$FILE"`
```

What is the right way to do this? And how can I easily check if the quotes are set right?

Comment: See also - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97560/are-quotes-needed-for-local-variable-assignment

Comment: See also [When is double-quoting necessary?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) and [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Comment: This is a good question, but given all the issues with embedded blanks, why would you make life hard on yourself by using them on purpose?

Comment: @Joe, with embedded blanks you mean space in the filenames? Personally I do not use them that often, but I am working with other peoples directories and files of which I am not certain if they contain spaces. Furthermore, I think it is better to get it right at once so I do not have to worry in the future.

Comment: Yes. What are we going to do with those "other people"? <G>

Answer (score 269, accepted):

In order from worst to best:

- `DIRNAME="$(dirname $FILE)"` [will not do what you want](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) if `$FILE` contains whitespace (or whatever characters `$IFS` currently contains) or globbing characters `\[?*`.
- `` DIRNAME=`dirname "$FILE"` `` is technically correct, but [backticks are not recommended for command expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) because of the extra complexity when nesting them and the extra backslash processing that happens within them.
- `DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILE")` is correct, but [only because this is an assignment to a scalar (not array) variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). If you use the command substitution in any other context, such as `export DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILE")` or `du $(dirname -- "$FILE")`, the lack of quotes will cause trouble if the result of the expansion contain whitespace or globbing characters.
- `DIRNAME="$(dirname "$FILE")"` (except for the missing `--`, see below) is the recommended way. You can replace `DIRNAME=` with a command and a space without changing anything else, and `dirname` receives the correct string.

To improve even further:

- `DIRNAME="$(dirname -- "$FILE")"` works if `$FILE` starts with a dash.
- `DIRNAME="$(dirname -- "$FILE" && printf x)" && DIRNAME="${DIRNAME%?x}" || exit` works even if `$FILE`'s dirname ends with a newline, since `$()` chops off newlines at the end of output, both the one added by `dirname` and the ones that may be part of the actual data.

You can nest command expansions as much as you like. With `$()` you always create a new quoting context, so you can do things like this:

```sh
foo "$(bar "$(baz "$(ban "bla")")")"
```

You do *not* want to try that with backticks.

Comment: Clear answer to my question. When I nest these variables, can I just keep on quoting like I do now?

Comment: Is there a reference/resource detailing the behavior of quotes within a command substition within quotes?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius "With `$()` you always create a new quoting context", so it's just like outside the outer quotes. There's nothing more to it, as far as I know.

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks, yeah, I found your explanation very clear. I was just wondering whether it was in a manual somewhere as well. [I did find it (albeit unofficially) at wooledge](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution#line-33). I guess if you read about order of substitution *carefully*, you could derive this fact as a result.

Comment: So nested quotes are acceptable, but they throw us off because most syntax coloring schemes don't detect the special circumstance. Neat.

Comment: Is it safe to have the deep-most execution as backticks? E.g. `foo "$(bar "$(baz "\`ban "bla"\`")")"`

Comment: @dma_k Sure, but why would you? It's inconsistent, more complicated, and makes for a bigger diff if you ever change the nesting.

Comment: I never used more than two "inclusions". And the place where it hurts is `Makefile` where dollar sign needs to be escaped `$$` (error-prone when it comes to copying from bash scripts), that is why I prefer backticks which is more "compatible" in the sense.

Comment: +1 for the quoted, nested command substitutions example at the end.

Comment: have any deeper examples of this for more complicating setups, e.g. with curl call, e.g. using `--data '{"key":"val"}'` and `"http://$url"` inside the command?  I dont need `--data '{"key":"$val"}'` but that would make it more interesting.

Comment: `--data '{"key":"$val"}'` would be best achieved by using `jq` with `--arg` or `--argjson` - see `man jq`.

Answer (score 24):

You can always show the effects of variable quoting with `printf`.

Word splitting done on `var1`:

```
$ var1="hello     world"
$ printf '[%s]\n' $var1
[hello]
[world]
```

`var1` quoted, so no word splitting:

```
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var1"
[hello     world]
```

Word splitting on `var1` inside `$()`, equivalent to `echo "hello" "world"`:

```
$ var2=$(echo $var1)
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var2"
[hello world]
```

No word splitting on `var1`, no problem with not quoting the `$()`:

```
$ var2=$(echo "$var1")
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var2"
[hello     world]
```

Word splitting on `var1` again:

```
$ var2="$(echo $var1)"
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var2"
[hello world]
```

Quoting both, easiest way to be sure.

```
$ var2="$(echo "$var1")"
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var2"
[hello     world]
```

#### Globbing problem

Not quoting a variable can also lead to glob expansion of its contents:

```
$ mkdir test; cd test; touch file1 file2
$ var="*"
$ printf '[%s]\n' $var
[file1]
[file2]
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var"
[*]
```

Note this happens after the variable is expanded only. It is not necessary to quote a glob during assignment:

```
$ var=*
$ printf '[%s]\n' $var
[file1]
[file2]
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$var"
[*]
```

Use `set -f` to disable this behaviour:

```
$ set -f
$ var=*
$ printf '[%s]\n' $var
[*]
```

And `set +f` to re-enable it:

```
$ set +f
$ printf '[%s]\n' $var
[file1]
[file2]
```

Comment: People tend to forget that word splitting is not the only problem, you may want to change your example to have `var1='hello   *    world'` to illustrate the globbing problem as well.

Answer (score 15):

Addition to the accepted answer:

While I generally agree with [@l0b0's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118438/117659) here, I suspect the placement of bare backticks in the "worst to best" list is at least partly a result of the assumption that `$(...)` is available everywhere. I realize that the question specifies Bash, but there are plenty of times when Bash turns out to mean `/bin/sh`, which may not always actually be the full Bourne Again shell.

In particular, the plain Bourne shell won't know what to do with `$(...)`, so scripts which claim to be compatible with it (e.g., via a `#!/bin/sh` shebang line) will likely misbehave if they are actually run by the "real" `/bin/sh` – this is of special interest when, say, producing init scripts, or packaging pre- and post-scripts, and can land one in a surprising place during installation of a base system.

If any of that sounds like something you're planning to do with this variable, nesting is probably less of a concern than having the script actually, predictably run. When it's a simple enough case and portability is a concern, even if I expect the script to *usually* run on systems where `/bin/sh` is Bash, I often tend to use backticks for this reason, with multiple assignments instead of nesting.

Having said all that, the ubiquity of shells which implement `$(...)` (Bash, Dash, et al.), leaves us in a good spot to stick with the prettier, easier-to-nest, and more recently preferred POSIX syntax in most cases, for all the reasons @l0b0 mentions.

Aside: this has shown up occasionally on StackOverflow, too –

- [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed? [duplicate] (Feb 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406408)
- [Shell Programming: What's the difference between $(command) and `command` (Jan 2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/1004235)

Comment: // , Excellent answer. I have run into backwards compatibility issues with /bin/sh in the past, too. Do you have any advice about how to deal with his problem using backwards compatible methods?

Comment: in my experience: sometimes you might need to change backticks into dollar paren enclosed, and not once has it ever helped (been necessary, to be specific) to change dollar paren enclosed into backticks. I only write backticks in my javascript code, and not in shell code.

Comment: Since 2008 at least, POSIX has supported `$()` command substitution. If a system's shell is more than 15 years old, the user knows more about its idiosyncrasies than we do. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03