# Why is it not required to double quote `$bar` in assignment `foo=$bar`?

Tags: bash, quoting, assignment

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32227/674

> The main places where it's safe not to use the double quotes are:
>
> - in an assignment: `foo=$bar` (but note that you do need the double quotes in `export "foo=$bar"` or in array assignments like
>     `array=("$a" "$b")`);

1. Does it mean that it is not required to double quote `$bar` in assignment `foo=$bar`? Why?
2. Why do we need the double quotes in `export "foo=$bar"` and in array assignments like `array=("$a" "$b")`?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362130/170373 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97560/170373

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo=$bar
```

is *safe* because it's an *assignment*, and an assignment to a scalar variable, using the scalar assignment syntax. It's a *scalar context*, only one value can be stored in `$var`, it would not make sense to split or glob `$bar`. If the expansion resulted in several words, the shell would need to somehow combine them again to be able to store them as one string in `$foo`.

It's different when you use:

```
foo=($bar)
```

Where you're assigning to an array variable. There it's a list context. You're assigning a number of words to elements of the array. split+glob occurs.

Also beware of the double-nature of things like `export`/`local`/`typeset`/`declare`/`readonly` in some shells (explained in more details at [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97560))

You'll notice that:

```
foo=$bar
```

is parsed as an assignment while

```
"foo"=$bar
```

is just an attempt to run the `foo=content_of_bar` command (where the content of bar is subject to split+glob).

In shells where `export` (and other `local`/`typeset`...) is both a keyword and builtin (ksh, bash and recent versions of zsh), in:

```
export foo=$bar
```

`export` is recognised as a *keyword* and `foo=$bar` as an assignment, so `$bar` is not subject to split+glob. But it takes little for `export` to stop being recognised as a *keyword*. In which case, it's just treated as a simple command and split+glob happens like in any argument to any other command.

And even in the cases where `export` is seen as a keyword, if the arguments don't look like variable assignments (like in the `"foo"=$bar` above), then they're treated like normal arguments and subject to split+glob again.

Comment: Define "list context".

Comment: Thanks. (1) "In shells where export (and other local/typeset...) is both a keyword and builtin (ksh, bash and recent versions of zsh)". I think `export` is only a builtin in bash? (2) "it takes little for export to stop being recognised as a keyword." How do you make it? How do you make that happen?

Comment: @Tim see the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your two questions, we first have to know what "being safe" means. Bash has a multitude of expansions and they all happen in a certain order. Usually when we say something is "safe", we mean that no unwilling word splitting happens. In this sense:

1. is "safe", i.e. no double quotes are required. To quote the bash manual:

   > A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
   >
   > ```
   >           name=[value]
   > ```
   >
   > If  value  is  not given, the variable is assigned the null string. 
   >   All values undergo **tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
   >   command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal (see
   >   EXPANSION below)**.

   Note that word splitting is not performed! So in that regard it is reasonably safe and executing `bar="rm asdf"; foo=$bar;` will not result in anything crazy, like failing to execute, or even your file being deleted, as `$foo` or `eval $foo` would. However, what *will* happen is variable expansion:

   `foo="Tomatoes are $50"` will result in `foo` having the content `Tomatoes are 0`. This may or may not be what you wanted.
2. works in a similar way:
   `foo="rm asdf"; export bar=$foo` will not remove your file and will parse correctly, and `foo="rm asdf"; array=($foo)` will parse too. Note that in the case of the array, word splitting actually *does* happen, so the first element of `array` will be `rm`.

   Also, you will still get the other expansion in both of those. I'm also fairly certain word splitting happens in the `export` case, it's just that exports accepts all of the words as arguments and parses it in the way you expect it to, similar to how `echo $foo` doesn't need quotes.

Out of all of these, I would call the array example the least safe one, because word splitting does happen and has a concrete effect. Therefore you will need double quotes in this case.

Comment: No, in `bar="*"; foo=$bar`, both `foo` and `bar` contain `*`. It's only if you do `echo $bar` instead of `echo "$bar"` that the `*` is then expanded.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're completely right, I just noticed too. I became suspicious after I read further in the bash manual. Shows me how careful one should be with expansion, I guess. I walked right into it :)