# How does `cat` work so that it allows reading a file line as an array element?

Tags: bash, cat, coreutils

In bash, we can read an file into an array, so that each line in the file becomes an element of the array.

```
$ arr=( $(cat myfile) )
```

I was wonder how `cat` works so that it allows reading a file line as an array element? Does `cat` separate the file content into lines?

Does `cat` not just read all the content of the file at once, without separating it into lines, so that  `arr` has just one single element, which is the entire content of the file? Thanks.

Comment: `cat` does not care what's in the file. It make no interpretation of the data whatsoever.

Comment: You know that [field splitting happens in array assignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383751/why-is-it-not-required-to-double-quote-bar-in-assignment-foo-bar). This isn't slow learning, this is no learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not cat, it's the =() if you use ="" it would not be an array.

```
$ A="$(echo -e "a\nb")"
$ echo $A
a b
$ echo "$A"
a
b
$ B=( $(echo -e "a\nb") )
$ echo $B
a
$ echo "${B[*]}"
a b
```