# Ambigious Redirect when using alias to export environment variable of path with spaces?

Tags: bash, windows, io-redirection, alias

I'm trying to simplify switching between `KANBANFILE`'s using [kanban.bash](https://github.com/coderofsalvation/kanban.bash) on Windows.

I'm using several aliases such as the following for switching between `KANBANFILE`s:

```
alias k.pos="export KANBANFILE=\"/c/Users/ajleer/OneDrive - Name Of SomeOneDrive/kanbandb/.kanban.pos.csv\""
```

but the following line breaks it in two different places with an [ambigious redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error) error which means that the file it's trying to read from isn't there:

```
update_item_status(){
  item="$( cat "${KANBANFILE}" | awk "{ if (NR==$1) print \$0 }" )"
  [[ ${#item} == 0 ]] && echo "item $1 not found" && exit 1 
  if [[ -n "$2" ]]; then  # status change 
    status="$(echo "$item" | awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/"//g' )"
    flags="$(echo "$item"  | awk -F',' '{ print $4 }' | sed 's/"//g' )"
    dates="$(echo "$item"  | awk -F',' '{ print $5 }' | sed 's/"//g' )"
    newflags="$flags${2:0:1}"
    newdates="$dates $(get_current_date)"
    [[ "$2" =~ "DONE" ]] && date="$(get_current_date)"
    newitem="$item"
    newitem="${newitem/$status/$2}"
    newitem="${newitem/$flags/$newflags}"
    newitem="${newitem/$dates/$newdates}"
    KANBANITEMS="$(<$KANBANFILE)"  # THE AMBIGUOUS REDIRECT Error Line
    echo "${KANBANITEMS//"$item"/"$newitem"}" > "${KANBANFILE}"
    echo "$status -> $2"
  fi
}
```

and also here:

```
update_item(){
  item="$( cat "${KANBANFILE}" | awk "{ if (NR==$1) print \$0 }" )"
  [[ ${#item} == 0 ]] && echo "item $1 not found" && exit 1 
  status="$(echo "$item" | awk -F',' '{ print $1 }')"
  echo '#
# STATUSES ARE: '${statuses[*]}' 
#
'"$item" > "${TMP}".update
  ${EDITOR} "${TMP}".update
  KANBANITEMS="$(<$KANBANFILE)" # THE AMBIGUOUS REDIRECT Error Line
  newitem="$(cat "${TMP}".update | tail -n1 )" 
  echo "${KANBANITEMS//"$item"/"$newitem"}" > "${KANBANFILE}"
  echo "updated item $1"
}
```

So how do I rewrite my KABANFILE export alias so that it doesn't break the code above, but so that I still can have spaces in the path pointing to the `.kanban.xxx.csv` file?

The `Ambigious Redirect` occurs anytime I use the `kanban <task-id>` or `kanban <task-id> <status>` [command](https://github.com/coderofsalvation/kanban.bash#commandline-overview) (even though that's really just editing the csv file with the default editor).

P.S. I am using git-bash on Windows aka MINGW64

Comment: Why didn't you quote `$KANBANFILE` in those lines, like you have quoted elsewhere?

Comment: Use `set -x` to show what your script does. You might see what's wrong with the problematic line.

Comment: @muru You mean in the script lines that are causing the error?  I didn’t write the script.  I did however notice that those are the only two lines where the ‘$KANBAN’ variable is referenced without quotes.

Comment: Then can you edit the script? If so, fix the quoting there.

Comment: @muru I actually tried that, but that would cause it to have quotes within the double quotes...ala: `KANBANITEMS="$(<\"$KANBANFILE\")"` it didn't fix the issue, unless the quotes are inside the variable too and that's somehow throwing it off..

Comment: @Bodo Is `set -x` to be run from inside the script?

Comment: @Bodo Or do you mean that I should run my alias command to see what's in there?

Comment: @leeand00 `KANBANITEMS="$(<"$KANBANFILE")"`

Comment: execute `set -x`, then run `update_item_status` or `update_item` to see what is causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes outside a command substitution are independent from the quotes *inside* it. So just quote `"$KANBANFILE"` like you do elsewhere.

```
$ filename="foo bar"
$ echo hello > "$filename"
$ echo "$( < $filename )"           #  $filename is not quoted
bash: $filename: ambiguous redirect

$ echo "$( < "$filename" )"         # "$filename" is quoted
hello
```

That said, in an assignment the outer quotes aren't strictly necessary, so `var=$(something)` works as well as `var="$(something)"` (Barring bugs).

See, e.g. [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373) and [Do I need to quote command substitutions when assigning their output to a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362130/170373)