# Mixing local and remote variables and proper usage and quotation

Tags: shell, quoting, remote, command-substitution, here-document

The recommended pattern for bash as far as I know is to always quote the shell variables.
E.g. `"$VAR"` instead of `$VAR`.
But how can I achieve the same safety the quotes provide for variables meant to be interpreted **remotely**?
E.g in the following:

```
ssh server.com<<CODE
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT= \$( ls /foo/bar/\$TARGET | wc -l )  
echo \$COUNT > count.txt    

CODE
```

For the code to work I need to escape `$COUNT` and `$TARGET`.
But how do I achieve the same safety that the "$COUNT" or "$TARGET" provides for this specific case?

**Update**
I have pasted only the part that is problematic.
I have also other lines that the variables are defined outside of the heredoc so if I use `<<'CODE'` then the snippet breaks.
For a more complete example:

```
SOME_STRING="SOME VALUE"  
ssh server.com<<CODE  
echo $SOME_VALUE > test_file.txt  # <--- does not work if I use <<'CODE'
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT= \$( ls /foo/bar/\$TARGET | wc -l )  
echo \$COUNT > count.txt    

CODE
```

Comment: It looks like you might have mixed up SOME_STRING with SOME_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like here-docs leave double quotes in place. For example, consider the following command:

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC
"this will still be quoted"
HEREDOC
```

This will produce the following quoted string as its output:

```
"this will still be quoted:
```

So you should just be able to quote your variables as usual:

```bsh
SOME_STRING="SOME VALUE"
ssh server.com<<CODE
echo "$SOME_VALUE" > test_file.txt
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT="\$( ls /foo/bar/\$TARGET | wc -l )"
echo "\$COUNT" > count.txt
CODE
```

Regarding quoting variables inside command substitutions, refer to the following post: [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

Note that I've copied your snippet verbatim, but it looks like you probably meant to use the variable `SOME_STRING` instead of `SOME_VALUE`. Here is a slightly modified version of your snippet that I can run locally with the expected results:

```bsh
mkdir -p "/foo/bar/target dir"

SOME_STRING="SOME VALUE"
ssh localhost<<CODE
echo "$SOME_STRING" > test_file.txt
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT="\$( ls "/foo/bar/\$TARGET" | wc -l )"
echo "\$COUNT" > count.txt
CODE
```

Comment: The command substitution should be quoted? And what about the `$TARGET` in the command substitution? That is unquoted in your code

Comment: Tried that. Breaks the script

Comment: Yes, you would probably want to quote `$TARGET` as well. But my point is that the quoting isn't being affected by the here-doc, so there isn't a difference between the local and remote quoting in this situation. Whether or not you want to quote the command substitution or anything else is up to you. A general rule of thumb is to quote everything that you want treated as a single token.

Comment: The snippet does not compile

Comment: Compile? You mean doesn't run as expected?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, I would suggest rewriting your example so that someone else can run it themselves as-is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67379/discussion-between-igal-and-jim).

Answer (score 0):

We seem to get variations on this question a lot over the last few days.

In this case, quote the here-document:

```
ssh server.com <<'CODE'
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT= $( ls /foo/bar/$TARGET | wc -l )  
echo $COUNT > count.txt    
then  
fi  
CODE
```

The `'CODE'` (as opposed to just `CODE`) will ensure that the here-document is passed to the utility as it is written, without expanding variables or performing command substitutions.

Note that you also have syntax errors in the here-document (spaces around `=` and no `if` ta match the `then`). You should also double-quote the expansions both `$COUNT` and `$TARGET` as usual.

```
ssh server.com <<'CODE'
TARGET="target dir"
COUNT=$( ls "/foo/bar/$TARGET" | wc -l )  
printf '%s\n' "$COUNT" >count.txt    
CODE
```

---

If you are trying to count the number of files in a remote directory, use this instead:

```
ssh server 'find "/path/to/dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo . \;' | wc -l
```

This will correctly count the number of files in `/path/to/dir`.

To write the result to a remote file:

```
ssh server 'find "/path/to/dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo . \; | wc -l >file'
```

---

If the code that you need to execute remotely is very complex, then it may be better to create a script on the server to run it.  The variable that you need to pass to the script can be passed on its command line:

```
ssh server ./script.sh "$SOME_VARIABLE"
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR="$1"

# do stuff
```

Comment: The reason I am not using singe quotes around the `CODE` is because the rest of the commands are not interpreted correctly. Without quotes it works

Comment: E.g. if I have the line `echo $SOME_VAR > ~/test_file.txt` if I use `<<'CODE` then the file is empty i.e. nothing is printed. And `SOME_VAR` is defined outside of the here doc

Comment: I updated post too

Comment: I have more code and the logic is more complex than just counting files. I just pasted the part that shows the issue

Comment: @Jim See updated end of my answer.

Comment: Very reasonable suggestion about another script. To be honest though it is not that complicated at this point to not just find a good trade off to what I am trying to do. I am interested to know if it is possible to have a good script the way I describe or is impossible and I need to create another script as you mentioned