# Sed command to delete lines - variable

Tags: shell-script, sed

Using sed command I want to delete every other three lines from a file which has e.g. 99 lines in total. I mean to keep the first three lines and delete the second three lines and so on.

My starting script is as below:

```
for i in `seq 1 6 99`; do
   sed '$i,${i+2}!d' test.txt > o$i.txt
done
cat o*.txt > O.txt
rm o*.txt
```

Individual i works fine, likes

```
sed '1,3!d' test.txt > o1.txt
sed '7,9!d' test.txt > o7.txt
...
```

But it doesn't works inside sed.
Would you please let me know where I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543022/sed-command-to-delete-lines-variable/543032#comment1006884_543022), you need proper quoting of your variables in your sed call:

```
for i in $(seq 1 6 99); do
    sed "$i"','"$((i+2))"'!d' test.txt > "o$i.txt"
done
```

Your variables are not expanded in singles quotes and taken literally (`$i` = insert before the last line). The expansion works with double quotes (no quotes also work in this example) and you need `$((…))` for the arithmetic evaluation and to output its result. The remaining parts of the script remain in single quotes.

You should also use the newer `$(…)` syntax for the command substitution instead of the deprecated backticks `` `…` `` which makes quoting easier. Here is a [good example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118438/332764).

---

But you can use GNU `sed`'s  [first~step](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses) operator instead of a loop:

```
sed '4~6{N;N;d}' file
```

Example:

```
$ seq 20 | sed '4~6{N;N;d}'
1
2
3
7
8
9
13
14
15
19
20
```

Explanation:

`sed '4~6d'` would delete line 4 and then each 6th line 10, 16, 22 ...

With `{N;N;d}` two additional lines are deleted which are 4,5,6, then 10,11,12 ...