# Bash: how to build JSON from multiline strings

Tags: bash, awk, json

My `awk` outputs a multiline string.

```bsh
awkresult=`awk '{...}'`
echo "{ \"result\": \"$awkresult\" }" > result.json
```

The multilines must be preserved in the result string.

I think the best way is to insert newlines at the end of each line in `awkresult`.

My `awk` script cannot be modified. How should I modify my code?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by you cannot modify your script? Additionally, could you please update your post to include the exact format you are expecting? Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of `awkresult` that includes newlines and the output you want to see in `result.json` given that input. Right now we're all making different guesses about whether you mean a literal linefeed character or the 2-character string `\n` in your input and your output.

Comment: Please note that the "backtick"-style for command substitutions is deprecated, and the `$( ... )` notation is the recommended standard. Also, [quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash) is an important subject when it comes to shell variables.

Comment: The multi line result is an error:
awk: cmd. line:1: {...}
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error

Answer (score 6):

Note that newlines in values must be encoded as `\n` in JSON. A JSON parser would decode these as real newlines. Insertin a *literal* newline in a value in a JSON file would result in a broken JSON document.

[Using `jo`](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) (a tool for generating JSON output in the shell, with the correct encoding etc.):

```
awkresult='some string
with newlines
the end'

jo result="$awkresult"
```

This would result in the output

```
{"result":"some string\nwith newlines\nthe end"}
```

To pretty print:

```
jo -p result="$awkresult"
```

which results in

```
{
   "result": "some string\nwith newlines\nthe end"
}
```

Redirect the output of `jo` to a file to save the output, e.g.

```
jo result="$awkresult" >result.json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HERE document like below :

```
echo "$(cat <<EOM
{ "result" : "$awkresult" }
EOM
)" > result.json
```

Note the double-quotes " in echo statement , it preservers all newlines and you dont have to escape \" quotes inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was right, but don't use double-quotes to encode the JSON string. Use single quotes around the `{..}`, use a special quoting sequence to expand the `awkresult` inside the single quotes

```
awkresult='foo\nbar\nzoo\n'
```

now, use the variable as

```
echo '{ "result": "'"$awkresult"'" }' > result.json
```

Also remember that the JSON specification does "not" allow literal newline control characters to be embedded. You can verify if the JSON snippet is valid

```
echo '{ "result": "'"$awkresult"'" }' | jq .
{
  "result": "foo\nboo\nbar\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted already will preserve newlines in `$awkresult`:

```
$ awkresult='foo
bar'
$ echo "{ \"result\": \"$awkresult\" }"
{ "result": "foo
bar" }
```

but here's a simpler, more robust, more portable, way to do the same:

```
awkresult="$(awk '{...}')"
printf '{ "result": "%s" }\n' "$awkresult" > result.jso
```

Or did you mean you have to replace newlines with `\n` strings like this

```
$ printf '{ "result": "%q" }\n' "$awkresult"
{ "result": "$'foo\nbar'" }
```

or something else?