# Environment variable expansion inside $(command substitution)

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, command-substitution

I'm running Bash 5.1.4 on Debian.

I'm writing a post-installation script to copy configuration and other files to locations in my home directory. I add the intended destination to each file at the beginning with a prefix; for example: `# DEST: $HOME/.config/mousepad/Thunar` (of course, in the script the file name will be substituted by a variable, and the hash symbol by the appropiate comment character; this line appears within the first 10 lines, not necessarily at the first, so I don't mess with shebangs).

To get these locations I'm using this command: `head Thunar.acs | egrep "DEST:" | awk '{print $3}`, which returns literally `$HOME/.config/Thunar`; I'd like it to expand `$HOME`. What I mean is when I try `ls $(head Thunar.acs | egrep "DEST:" | awk '{print $2})` I get the error `ls: cannot access '$HOME/.config/Thunar/': No such file or directory`. I read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash) and tried all of the combination of double quotes in the selected answer, but I still got the error. How can I solve this?

Enclosing the variable name in braces doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command substitutions and variable expansions aren't recursive. That is, when the shell expands something like `$varname` or `$(somecommand)`, it doesn't then scan the result for additional instances of `$varname` or `$(somecommand)` to expand. The only thing it does to the result is try to split it into "words" and expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard; these cause more trouble than anything else, so you should almost always double-quote the expansion so it just gets left alone.

If you do want `$HOME` expanded to the actual home path, the simplest ways I see are to pipe it through `envsubst` (which will expand anything that looks like an environment variable reference, but note that it only works with *environment* variables, not unexported shell variables), or have `awk` do the substitution (which'll only do the specific variable(s) you tell it to replace).

Before I show how to do this, I have to object to using three tools -- `head`, `egrep`, and `awk` -- when `awk` is perfectly capable of doing the entire job itself:

```
awk '/DEST:/ {print $3}; (NR>=10) {exit}' Thunar.acs
```

The `/DEST:/` bit does the job `egrep` did in the original, and `(NR>=10) {exit}` replaces `head -n 10`.

So, here's a version using `envsubst`:

```
ls "$(awk '/DEST:/ {print $3}; (NR>=10) {exit}' Thunar.acs | envsubst)"
```

(Note the double-quotes to keep word-splitting and wildcard expansion from doing anything weird.)

Here's a version using `awk`'s `sub` function to do the replacement:

```
ls "$(awk -v home="$HOME" '/DEST:/ {sub("\\$HOME",home,$3); print $3}; (NR>=10) {exit}' Thunar.acs)"
```

Comment: @mathbekunkus That's extremely strange. If you just run `awk '/DEST:/ {print $3}; (NR>=10) {exit}' Thunar.acs`, what does it print?

Comment: False alarm; I had some extra characters in the paste clipboard; I used it again and worked. However, `(NR>=10)` still returns every third record of every line; also, using `\$HOME` gives a warning, whereas using `\\$HOME` doesn't. I deleted the commment out of shame, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: another comment for space concerns. If I run the string you suggest in your comment, I also get every third field.

Comment: @mathbekunkus I think you're using `gawk` (I have `mawk` as default where I was testing); apparently `gawk` complains about `\$HOME`, but `mawk` allows it. `\\$HOME` or `[$]HOME` will work with either implementation. But I have no idea what'd make *any* version of `awk` print the third column of lines that don't contain "DEST:".

Comment: (1) Thanks for banging on the “you should almost always double-quote the expansion … the double-quotes … keep word-splitting and wildcard expansion from doing anything weird” drum.  But, unless `IFS` is set to something weird, your concern is a *little* misplaced here — if the pathname (in the file) contains whitespace, your `print $3` already breaks it.  If the “prefix” is known (predetermined), you could handle pathnames with whitespace with ``{ sub("# DEST: ", ""); sub("\\$HOME", home); print }``.  Cases where the prefix isn’t predetermined can be handled with a little more work. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) This is out of scope for this question, but note that your current code would change `$HOMEDRIVE` to `/home/gordonDRIVE`. Obviously you could fix that with `sub("\\$HOME/", home "/")` or equivalent. (3) User beware: if there are multiple `DEST:` lines in the first ten lines, then you will get all the pathnames, concatenated, separated by newlines. You can fix that by adding `exit` to the `/DEST:/` action (after the `print`).