# Directories printed instead of */

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file like this

```
/*
 
  Created by Bla bla bla
  Copyright by XYZ
  December 20th, 2020

*/

"car" = "Carro";
"door" = "Porta";
```

I would like to read this file line by line and copy to another file.

So I have this bash script

```
file='file.txt'
output='output.txt'
touch $output

for oneLine in $(cat ${file})
do
  echo "$oneLine" >> $output
done
```

when I open the output file this is what I see

```
/*
 
  Created by Bla bla bla
  Copyright by XYZ
  December 20th, 2020

Project/
Files/
Images/
Sounds/
```

in other words, when the parsing arrives at the line containing the `*\` it prints a list of directories that in fact are directories that exist at the same level of the input and the output files.

How do I solve that?

Comment: You are in effect using the file contents as a pattern for `for`. Hence it expands i.e. `*/` to all files in current directory. Try `echo */`, or `for f in */; do echo "# $f #"; done` Not sure how you manage to get the whole lines from start of script. (First 6 lines). Suspect it's not your entire script. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 - Wrote more in an answer but it got closed before I had a chance to post :P

Comment: the unquoted `$(cat ${file})` triggers word splitting _and_ filename generation, and `*/` is a pattern that matches all directories in the current dir. See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash) (That `/*` should also already expand to some filenames, like `/bin`, `/etc`)

Comment: Also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) has a loop that works, and an explanation why you shouldn't do stuff line-by-line in the shell. You could get the result you're trying to get here more easily with just the single command `cat -- "$file" > "$output"`. (Or if you're actually trying to do something other than just copy, with an appropriate sed or awk script.)