# Difference between echo $(cal) and echo "$(cal)" [bash]

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm a linux noob.

When I type `echo $(cal)` in bash it prints calendar without any formatting.

But when i type `echo "$(cal)"`  it prints the complete formatted calendar.

What is the distinction between these 2 commands ?

btw, this case is described in the book **The Linux Command Line by *William E. Shotts, Jr.*** `[in 7th chapter's command substitution section ]` but I couldn't get it :(

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like missing quotes. It'll also point out that `echo "$(somecommand)"` is just an overcomplicated way to run `cal`. I recommend running your scripts through it, at least until you get more experience.

Comment: See also: [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373)