# looping through a folder which has spaces, passed as an argument in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've read a ton of answers that are close to what I need, but not exactly, and I can't figure out how to adapt them to my needs.

I'd like to take write a bash script that takes a source folder as an argument, and perform a bunch of operations on every file (of certain type) in that folder.

```
src_dir=$1

for file in $src_dir/*.jpg; do
    filename=`basename "$file"`
    basename="${filename%.*}"
    ...
done
```

works if there are no spaces in src_dir, but I cannot figure out how to make this work if there are spaces. Usually `"$src_dir"` works, but this doesn't work with `for file in` .

EDIT: I should mention, I would like to be able to pass paths that contains variables that need expanding (`$HOME`, `$MY_PROJECT_PATH` etc. so single tick ' is also not ideal)

Comment: mandatory reading [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) and [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say it doesn't work with quotes, then I'm assuming that you have quoted *the whole* `$src_dir/*.jpg` bit.  Then, yes, it would not work as `*` stops being a globbing character in a quoted string.

However, if you just quote `$src_dir`, it will work:

```bsh
src_dir=$1

for pathname in "$src_dir"/*.jpg; do
    name_noext=$( basename -- "$pathname" .jpg )
    ...
done
```

This leaves `*` unquoted, which makes the shell use it as a globbing character.

As for your edit: When the script is called with e.g. `$HOME`, I'm assuming it is called with the *expansion* of the `HOME` variable, not with the literal string `$HOME`.  It would be incredibly problematic if the script would have to test whether the supplied directory path contained literal variable names, which would include having to decide whether the string `$HOME` was a variable or the literal name of a directory (which it could technically be).  This is unrelated to the expansion of `$src_dir` for your loop.

Comment: thanks! Very pleasantly surprised that the answer is so simple :P

Answer (score 1):

You only need to double-quote `src_dir`. Also, if you don't want to pollute your shell with random variables, use a subshell: `(src_dir=$1; for file in "$src_dir"/*.jpg; do ... done)`