# Quoting within $(command substitution) in argument to a function in bash

Tags: bash

I've looked at [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash) and still don't get what I do incorrectly (my code looks to me like "is the recommended way" from accepted answer) and how to fix it:

```
print_and_run(){
    echo next line: "$1"
    echo "$($1)"
}

print_and_run 'sed --in-place -- "s|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|" .git/config' 
next line: sed --in-place -- "s|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|" .git/config
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

`sed` line works on its own, function `print_and_run` works for commands w/out quotes, e.g `print_and_run 'cat ./.git/config'`. TIA

P.S. btw not sure it matters: I wrote `echo "$($1)"` not `echo $($1)` to print with newlines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character, and now I see the former looks like "is the recommended way").

Comment: you probably don't want to use `echo "$(foo)"`, it's almost the same as just `foo`, except that it removes any trailing newlines from the output and then adds exactly one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps try it in a different way:

```
print_and_run() {
    printf "next line:"
    printf " '%s'" "$@"
    printf "\n"

    echo "$("$@")"
}

print_and_run sed --in-place -- "s|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|" .git/config
```

Result:

```
next line: 'sed' '--in-place' '--' 's|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|' '.git/config'
```

In this example, the original quoting is preserved. However, things like pipes or redirections still won't work.

A completely different approach would be to rely on the shell's built in command printing:

```
 set -x
 sed --in-place -- "s|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|" .git/config
 set +x
```

It will print a line like this:

```
+ sed --in-place -- 's|fetch = +refs/\*:refs/\*|fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|' .git/config
```

So you don't have to implement your own print command at all, the shell already does it for you.

Comment: Nice thing will be to be able to put any command into argument and don't think about formatting, but I seriously doubt bash supports that, both of your solutions are fine for my current goals. Thanks. 
Are substitutions made by bash (e.g. quotes in your example) always safe to copy a line from `+` and be able to run it as it is?

Comment: you probably don't want to use `echo "$(foo)"`, it's almost the same as just `foo`, except that it removes any trailing newlines from the output and then adds exactly one