# echo ${hostname}; vs echo $(hostname);

Tags: shell, hostname

Could you please explain the difference between:

`echo ${hostname};`
and `echo $(hostname);`

`echo ${hostname};` - shows nothing, just an empty line.
`echo $(hostname);` - shows information from /etc/hostname.

tested on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and CentOS 7

Comment: do you mean `echo $HOSTNAME` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Hi. no, it is exactly like it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${hostname}` or `$hostname` is called [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and here it gives the value of the shell variable `hostname`. It's probably unset, so you get the empty string which gets removed during word splitting since the expansion is not quoted. But you could of course define it, and Bash would automatically fill the uppercase `HOSTNAME` with the hostname.

See e.g. [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/170373)

```
$ hostname=foo
$ echo "$hostname"
foo
```

`$(hostname)` is called [*command substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), and here it runs the command `hostname` and gives its output.

```
$ hostname
ulpukka
$ foo=$(hostname)
$ echo "$foo"
ulpukka
```

Word splitting applies to both unquoted parameter expansions and command substitutions, see e.g. [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)