# Modifying a path

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I'm trying to modifying a path stored in a variable (`$var`) through `sed`. In truth, I need to replace `$(dirname "$var")` for reasons related to the purpose of my script.

An example of `var` is `var=/dir/dir xyz/file.txt`, while `filename` contains several paths to be substituted which could be in any position (once near the middle of the line, another at the beginning, etc). Below I try to give an example of `filename`:

```
dog foo/bar /dir/dir xyz/file.txt
a b c d /dir/dir xyz/file.txt x y z
/dir/dir xyz/file.txt 1234
{[(/dir/dir xyz/file.txt
```

What I want is

```
dog foo/bar .
a b c d . x y z
. 1234
{[(.
```

I tried the following

```
sed "s|"$(dirname "$var")"|.|g" "$filename"
```

obtaining `` sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command ``

Could you help me? Of course, you could suggest another way besides `sed`.

Comment: "not sure if I should enclose also the $() with the double quotes `""`)" -- _yes._

Comment: see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) and [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/170373). Here, you're explicitly ending the quoted part before the command substitution and restarting it after it. Note that regardless of quotes, you'll have issues there if the filename contains characters special to sed, like `.*`, or backslash, or the `|` you used as separator

Comment: @ilkkachu it's not working even if I double quote `$(dirname "$VAR")`

Comment: Don't use any variation of `--in-place` while testing or in your question - add that on your own after you get an answer to your problem if you like as it's completely irrelevant and so just clutters your question.

Comment: What do you have in `VAR`? How are you setting it? Show how you run it. _Show what you're doing and what happens._ Would the output of `dirname` ever be `/dir/dir xyz/file.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

> ```
> sed "s|"$(dirname "$var")"|.|g" "$filename"
> ```

The `s|` and `|.|g` are being quoted, but the `$(dirname "$var")` is out of the quotes, and is therefore subject to split+glob.

```
sed -e "s|$(dirname -- "$var")|.|g" -- "$filename"
```

Would fix that (also adding the missing `--`s), but that's still wrong as the left-hand side of the `s/lhs/rhs/flags` in `sed` is interpreted as a regex (not to mention that you can run into serious problems if `$var` contained `|` characters; and `sed` works with text, while file names are not guaranteed to be).

For instance, `.` there matches any character, not just `.`.

You should rather do:

```
DIR="$(dirname -- "$var")" perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{DIR}\E/./g' < "$filename"
```

For that to work with arbitrary file paths¹.

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking for arbitrary file paths, including those that contain newline characters, we'd need to add the `-0777` option (slurp mode) to `perl` and couldn't use command substitution which strips trailing newline characters. That could be done by passing the full `$var` to `perl` and use perl's `dirname()` (from the `File::Basename` module).</sup>

Comment: Why a `|` inside `$var` could lead to serious problems? Furthermore, I don't know Perl, is there a more safe way to do my substitution using bash/sed/awk?

Comment: Because `|` is the delimiter used for that `s` command. For instance if `$var` is `.*|reboot|e; #/whatever`, the sed command would become `s|.*|reboot|e; #|.|g` and reboot.

Comment: This means we can never use `sed` because there is always the possibility that someone can put a `.*|reboot|e;` in a text. So, what can I use in my bash script to do the substitution?

Comment: @user9952796 See [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059) if you have to use `sed`, but `perl` has rendered those sed/awk commands obsolete over 35 years ago, you may want  to move on.

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean `--` ?

Comment: @user9952796 see [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210)

Comment: How could I edit `$filename` in place with `perl`? For the moment it shows the substitution into the shell. In addition, is there a way to break your command in two separated line (that is, one line for `DIR` definition and the next for the `perl` command)? It's only for better readability

Comment: `perl` has a `-i` option for in-place editing. Some `sed` implementations have actually borrowed if from `perl`. `VAR=value cmd args` is the syntax to call `cmd` with `VAR=value` in its environment. Separating it out would result into something completely different.

Comment: Tried to add `-i` option, but I get `Warning: Use of "-i" without parentheses is ambiguous at -e line 1.`

Comment: `perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{DIR}\E/./g' file`. You'll find thousands of Q&A here using this kind of constructs. See `perldoc perlrun` for details.

Comment: I tried the following two lines and seem to work. I'd like to ask you if there are some security issues: `dir=$(dirname -- "$var")` and below `perl -i -p -e "s|$dir|.|" "$filename"`

Comment: Of course, you're expanding the variable into the perl code which introduces a command injection vulnerability like in the sed case. You're also missing the `--` so if `$filename` is `-esystem"reboot"` for instance, that will reboot. As a general rule:  **do not** embed unsanitised data in an argument that is interpreted as *code*, whether that's sed, perl, awk, eval, sh code... or any language that can do more than what you want it to.

Comment: So, what's the way to do not expand `$dir` into `sed`, `perl`, `awk`, etc. ?

Comment: I already showed one for `perl`. You pass the data via some other mean (env var, separate argument, files, standard input...) and tell your code to access that data from there (like `$ENV{var}` here). `perl`, `sh`, `awk`, `python`, `php` can do it easily. `sed` can't so you're only left sanitising the data there.

Comment: Could you provide the other ways (separate argument and standard input) using `perl`? However, I don't understand why `perl` (or `bash`, etc.) accessing an environment variable is more secure than expanding the same variable inside the `perl` code. In both cases `$var` could store malicious code,

Comment: Another question: are Python, Java or C++ prone to command injection when performing the task I need in this post (replacing a path in a text file) ? I mean, a whole program written in one if these languages, so no use of `bash` or `perl`

Comment: Here the problem is that you have one language interpreter (the shell) feeding data as code to another language interpreter (perl, sed, awk...). You'd have the same problem if you did something as silly in any other language. `python` is similar to `perl`, just trendier these days (a lot less now with their fiasco update to 3; and it's also a lot less adapted than perl to text processing). `python`, `perl` ,`sh` all have a `eval` command to evaluate data as code without even having  to explicitly invoke a separate interpreter.

Comment: I mean programs that don't use `eval`

Comment: Hi, sorry for reviving this post. Today I just saw that `sed` has an option called `--sandbox`. The manual states "In sandbox mode, e/w/r commands are rejected - programs containing them will be aborted without being run. Sandbox mode ensures sed operates only on the input files designated on the command line, and cannot run external programs." Could this option solve the security issue arising when a file named `.*|reboot|e; #/whatever` is processed? Thank you

Comment: @user9952796, that would be for the GNU implementation of `sed`. Malicious `$var`s could still cause infinite loops and memory exhaustion, so there would still be security issues, only less severe (assuming `sed` doesn't have bugs in its parser that could lead to an ACE, language interpreters should not be fed untrusted code in general).

Comment: Could you provide an example of how `$var` could cause an infinite loop? Thanks

Comment: @user9952796, try for instance `(set -x; var='^|x|;:1;H;g;b1;#/x'; echo | sed --sandbox "s|$(dirname -- "$var")|.|g")`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be all you're trying to do, using any sed and assuming your variable doesn't contain any `:`s:

```
$ var='/dir/dir xyz/file.txt'
$ sed "s:$var:.:" file
dog foo/bar .
a b c d . x y z
. 1234
{[(.
```

I don't know why you were calling `dirname`. Also, if you aren't going to us `/` as the sed delimiter, don't use a regexp metacharacter like `|` as that just obfuscates your code at best, pick a character like `:` that's always literal. And don't use all-upper-case variable names for non-environment variables, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Given [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741108/replacing-a-path-containing-spaces/741111?noredirect=1#comment1407855_741111), if you really do need to call `dirname` for some reason then you could do:

```
$ sed "s:$(dirname "$var"):.:" file
dog foo/bar ./file.txt
a b c d ./file.txt x y z
./file.txt 1234
{[(./file.txt
```

Comment: I need to make `dirname $var` for other reasons related to the purpose of my script.