# ls, mv, cp, cat, vi, command not found

Tags: bash, path, bashrc

I was trying to add a new path to my bashrc file but I have seemed to messed something up. after I $ source ~/.bashrc I no longer can use the commands ls, mv, cp, cat, vi, and probably others that I haven't tried yet. Is there anyway I can reset the path so it all comes back?

```
[rn1041@cluster ~]$ ls
-bash: ls: No such file or directory
[rn1041@cluster ~]$ rm
-bash: rm: No such file or directory
[rn1041@cluster ~]$ cp
-bash: cp: No such file or directory
[rn1041@cluster ~]$ mv
-bash: mv: No such file or directory
[rn1041@cluster ~]$ echo path
path
```

Answer (score 3):

Most commonly used commands (including the ones you tried) are in `/bin`,
so you can run them by typing `/bin/ls`, etc.

P.S. What you meant to do is `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: ... and it will report "no command_you_are_searching_for in ()", because it also searches in PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an original, untouched ~/.bashrc from CentOS 6.

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:your/path/here
```

Comment: And what he probably did instead was, `export PATH=/your/path/here`.  By the way, it's advisable to [quote variable assignments when using `export`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569/135943).

Comment: It's *advisable* to quote *all* references to shell variables (unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing).  P.S. As a special case, it's unnecessary for simple assignments, like `FOO=$BAR`, but it doesn't hurt, and it's better for a beginner to get into the habit of always doing it.

Comment: P.S. Another common mistake is `export PATH=PATH:/your/path/here`.