# What are the contexts where Bash doesn't perform word splitting and globbing?

Tags: bash, wildcards, variable-substitution, syntax

Bash doesn't perform word splitting in globbing in these cases:

- LHS or RHS of an assignment, except for indexed arrays

  ```bsh
  var=$value                                # simple variable
  declare -A hash
  key="key with a space"
  hash[$key]=$value                         # index of an associative array

  arr=$(echo "1 2 3")                       # word splitting does happen here
  ```
- Inside `[[ ]]`

  ```bsh
  var="one two"
  if [[ $var = *" "* ]]; then ...           # check if var has a space in it
  if [[ $(echo "one two") = $var ]]; then   # use the output of command substitution to compare with var
  ```
- Inside `(( ))`

  ```bsh
  ((sum = $(echo "99 + 1")))                  # assigns 100 to sum
  ```
- In herestring

  ```bsh
  cat <<< *                                 # gives '*' as the output
  ```

Is there a definite list of cases where Bash does or doesn't perform word splitting and globbing?

Comment: `cat <<< $var` does word splitting (followed by joining with space) but not globbing in older versions. For redirections, that depends on whether the posix/sh mode is enabled and the shell is interactive or not.

Comment: Related: [What is (exactly) "list context" (and "string context")?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/382914)

Comment: Note that "indexed array" is the retronym for ordinary arrays, in contrast to associative array. You are talking about the index *to* an associative array.

Comment: `case $foo in` is another. I'm not sure about arguments to parameter expansion; `foo="a * b"` survives unexpanded in both `"${bar:-$foo}"` and `${bar:-"$foo"}`. I don't recall the details, but I think there is a comment in the source to the effect that the argument itself is not subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: I asked the same question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50537980/6862601) to see if it gets more attention there.

Comment: Gilles's answer to the reverse question [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) also has a list of these situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's typically the cases where it can't or it wouldn't make sense, so the non-list contexts. There are however non-list contexts where it does it, but complains when it results in more than one item, or joins those items with spaces.

Also, it's important to make the distinction between just wildcard pattern matching and filename generation or globbing, which is the generation of a list of file names that match a pattern.

For instance in `[[ foo = * ]]`, there is no globbing, as in that `*` is not expanded to the list of non-hidden files in the current directory, but that `*` is still interpreted as a pattern (here it returns true as `foo` matches the `*` pattern).

By splitting here, we're referring to the implicit splitting that is done upon unquoted parameter expansion (`$param`), command substitution (`$(...)` and `` `...` ``), and arithmetic expansion (`$((...))` and `$[...]`), using the `$IFS` special parameter in [list contexts](/a/382914).

We'll take `*` as an example below. As a pattern, it matches any sequence of characters. As a glob it expands to all the non-hidden files in the current directory (subject to `dotglob`, `GLOBIGNORE`...).

The below applies to `bash`, there are variations in other shells.

### Cases where splitting and globbing don't occur:

- when quoted (with `'*'`, `"*"`, `\*`, `$'*'`, `$"*"`).
- inside here documents (whether the delimiter is quoted or not):

  ```
  cat << EOF
  *
  EOF
  cat << 'EOF'
  *
  EOF
  ```
- inside arithmetic expressions:

  - `echo $((2 * 2))` (`*` is not globbed but `$((...))` undergoes split+glob, try after `IFS=4`)
  - `array[2 * 2]=4` / `${array[2 * 2]}` / `exec {array[2*2]}>&1`. Beware that you need the quotes in `unset -v 'a[1]'` (`[1]` is a wildcard).
  - `((2 * 2))`
  - `echo $[2 * 2]`
- scalar variable assignment:

  - `var=*`
  - `array[x]=*`
  - `hash[key]=*`
  - `array=([1]=*)` (older versions of `bash` used to do globbing there though and do something different when there was a file called `1=foo` in the current directory for instance).
  - `var+=*`
- in associative array keys:

  - `typeset -A hash; hash[**]=value; v=${hash[**]}`. `*` and `@` are special though.
- in assignments after `export`/`local`/`typeset`/`declare`/`readonly` under some circumstances only: the assignment keyword and the variable name and `=` must not be quoted even in part, and not be the result of any expansion. assignments and redirections may occurs before, but `command` can't be used.:

  - OK (no split+glob):

    - `export a=*`
    - `x=1 < /dev/null export foo a=*`
  - not OK (split+glob performed):

    - <strike>`""export a=*`</strike>
    - <strike>`command export a=*`</strike> (except in POSIX mode)
    - <strike>`export "a"=*`</strike>
    - <strike>`export a\=*`</strike>
    - <strike>`"$(echo export)" a=*`</strike>

  more on that at [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97560)
- `case * in (...); esac`
- `case x in (*); esac` (no split+glob, but that `*` is treated as a pattern, that also applies to wildcard found inside unquoted expansions as in `var=*; case x in ($var)`).
- inside `[[...]]`. Though note that pattern matching is done if unquoted wildcards are present on the right hand side of `=`, `==`, `!=` operators there.
- in here strings since version 4.4. In earlier versions, splitting (though not globbing) was done and the resulting words joined with spaces.
- in the target of redirections when the shell is in POSIX mode and non-interactive: `bash -o posix -c 'echo test > *'`. Otherwise, split+glob will be performed and `bash` will report an error if that expands to a list with less or more than 1 element.

Comment: I hesitate, but may I add to @Stéphane 's list the body of a function definition? In `fun() { echo a * b; }`, the `a * b` remains as is, and is  splitted and globbed only when calling `fun`.