# How to check if stdin is /dev/null from the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, devices, stdin

On Linux, is there a way for a shell script to check if its standard input is redirected from the null device (1, 3) <sup>*</sup>, ideally without reading anything?

The expected behavior would be:

```
./checkstdinnull
-> no
./checkstdinnull < /dev/null
-> yes
echo -n | ./checkstdinnull
-> no

EDIT

mknod secretunknownname c 1 3
exec 6<secretunknownname
rm secretunknownname
./checkstdinnull <&6
-> yes
```

I suspect I "just" need to read the maj/min number of the input *device*. But I can't find a way of doing that from the shell.

---

<sup>*</sup>No necessary just `/dev/null`, but *any* null device even if manually created with `mknod`.

Comment: Do you need to know if it's `/dev/null`, or just that it's not a tty?

Comment: The output of `{ readlink -f /dev/stdin; } <&6` for the case where you used exec and removed the node is `/root/secretunknownname (deleted)`. As it shows that the file got deleted: Isn't that enough for what you need?

Comment: I *need* (actually "needed") to know if the standard input was the null device.

Comment: I am trying to find my way in a (very poorly designed!) industrial system. And it sometimes maps input of worker utility to the null device, or, some other times, to the actual hardware device. In both cases using the same code, but with different major/minor dev numbers. We are trying to track when (and why!) it sometimes chose to use one or the other. For now, the `stat` solution is the only one working.

Comment: "So, the example on your EDIT doesn't really reproduce the problem that you describe, or: does it?" It does. Input in redirected from the null _device_. Which is usually accessed through `/dev/null`, but not necessary. You can "alias" is with `mknod` s illustrated in my example.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't @isaac?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On linux, you can do it with:

```
stdin_is_dev_null(){ test "`stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/stdin`" = "`stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/null`"; }
```

On a linux without stat(1) (eg. the busybox on your router):

```
stdin_is_dev_null(){ ls -Ll /proc/self/fd/0 | grep -q ' 1,  *3 '; }
```

On *bsd:

```
stdin_is_dev_null(){ test "`stat -f %Z`" = "`stat -Lf %Z /dev/null`"; }
```

On systems like *bsd and solaris, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/fd/0` and `/proc/PID/fd/0` are not "magical" symlinks as on linux, but character devices which will switch to the real file *when opened*. A stat(2) on their path will return something different than a fstat(2) on the opened file descriptor.

This means that the linux example will not work there, even with GNU coreutils installed. If the  versions of GNU stat(1) is recent enough, you can use the `-` argument to let it do a fstat(2) on the file descriptor 0, just like the stat(1) from *bsd:

```
stdin_is_dev_null(){ test "`stat -Lc %t:%T -`" = "`stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/null`"; }
```

It's also very easy to do the check *portably* in any language which offers an interface to fstat(2), eg. in `perl`:

```
stdin_is_dev_null(){ perl -e 'exit((stat STDIN)[6]!=(stat "/dev/null")[6])'; }
```

Comment: As the device type of `/dev/null` is `1:3`, you could test for that immediately.

Comment: FWIW the question was not about shell syntax. For what is concerning my issue, if the answer had only pointed me to the `stat` command I would have already been quite satisfied. I don't see the point in starting an editing war between `\`` and `$(` supporters. Personally, I prefer `$(...)` and there are some POSIX rationales in favor of that syntax (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03 ) But I don't see the point in downvoting an otherwise correct answer for something not related with the question.

Comment: Could someone explain why `$( ... )` is preferred over backticks in the context of this answer?

Comment: "_what bug does that fix_"? It doesn't fix a bug. The `$(..)` style nests more easily and AIUI is the POSIX preferred approach. I certainly hadn't intended to start any form of editing war, preferring to comment with a suggestion rather than change your excellent answer.

Comment: @user1717828 see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/100397) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/100397) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446388/100397) for some clarity.

Answer (score 15):

On Linux, to determine whether standard input is redirected from `/dev/null`, you can check whether `/proc/self/fd/0` has the same device and inode as `/dev/null`:

```
if [ /proc/self/fd/0 -ef /dev/null ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

You can use `/dev/stdin` instead of `/proc/self/fd/0`.

If you want to check whether standard input is redirected from the null device, you need to compare major and minor device numbers, for example using `stat` (see also [mosvy’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484232/86440)):

```
if [ "$(stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/stdin)" = "$(stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/null)" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

or, if you don’t care about this being [Linux-specific](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html),

```
if [ "$(stat -Lc %t:%T /dev/stdin)" = "1:3" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Comment: -ef, True if FILE1 and FILE2 refer to the same device and inode

Comment: very cool. `bash -c 'ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 /dev/null; [[ /proc/self/fd/0 -ef /dev/null ]] && echo dev null'` then do that again with `</dev/null`. +1

Comment: The `/dev/stdin` being a symlink to the original file is specific to Linux, so all those solutions are Linux-specific anyway. The `stat`-based ones require GNU or busybox `stat`. With recent versions of GNU `stat`, you can use `stat -` to do a `fstat()` on fd 0 which would then work on non-Linux systems.

Comment: @Stéphane the last part is exactly the situation the OP ran into, which is why I wrote up both solutions, distinguishing between `/dev/null` and the null device.

Comment: Oops, missed that.

Comment: Note that `-ef` may not available in all implementations of test (and is not in POSIX). It should be doing the same thing as the stat version (which is, unfortunately, not in POSIX either).

Answer (score 4):

Portably, to check that stdin is the `null` device (open on `/dev/null` or not (like a copy of `/dev/null`)), with `zsh` (whose `stat` builtin predates both GNU and FreeBSD `stat` by the way (not IRIX' though))):

```
zmodload zsh/stat
if [ "$(stat +rdev -f 0)" = "$(stat +rdev /dev/null)" ]; then
  echo stdin is open on the null device
fi
```

(note that it doesn't say if the file descriptor was open in read-only, write-only or read+write mode).

To check that it's open on the current `/dev/null` file specifically (not `/some/chroot/dev/null` for instance), on Linux only (where `/dev/stdin` is implemented as a symlink to the file open on fd 0 instead of a special device which when open acts like a `dup(0)` in other systems):

```
if [ /dev/stdin -ef /dev/null ]; then
  echo stdin is open on /dev/null
fi
```

On non-Linux, you can try:

```
if sh -c 'lsof -tad0 -p"$$" /dev/null' > /dev/null 2>&-; then
  echo stdin is open on /dev/null
fi
```