# Read a variable with "read" and preserve backslashes entered by the user

Tags: shell, read

I'm using `read` to read a path from a user like so:

```
read -p "Input the file name: " FilePath
```

The user now enters this string:

```
\Supernova\projects\ui\nebula
```

What can I do to replace `\` with `/`. The result I want is:

```
/Supernova/projects/ui/nebula
```

By the way, the command:

```
echo $FilePath
```

outputs the result:

```
Supernovaprojectsuinebula
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: See also: [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `read` treats backslash in its input as an escape operator (to escape the separators when using `read word1 word2` and the newline to allow line continuation).

To do what you want, you need to add the `-r` switch to `read` which tells it not to do that backslash processing, and you also need to set `$IFS` to the empty string so it treats the whole line as the whole word to assign to the variable¹:

```
IFS= read -rp "Input file name: " FilePath
UnixPath="${FilePath//\\//}"
```

Additionally, your `echo` commands [needs double quotes around the variable substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote): `echo "$FilePath"`, and anyway in general [`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803)², so:

```
printf '%s\n' "$FilePath"
```

---

<sup>¹ with the default value of `$IFS`, to prevent it from stripping leading and trailing blanks (space and tab) from the input line</sup>

<sup>² and for `echo` as well, backslash is or can be treated specially, even in `bash` depending on the environment or how it  was built.</sup>

Comment: @ Joseph R. - I get it that echo '\Supernova\projects\ui\nebula' get result is right:/Supernova/projects/ui/nebula. But is it possable to unuse quotes to get: /Supernova/projects/ui/nebula ? Because when I must do this: read -p "Input the file name : " FilePath   then: echo $FilePath,but get Supernovaprojectsuinebula in this way. So I can't use single quotes.

Comment: @binghenzq Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @binghenzq Also, if you don't mind, I took the liberty of editing your question with this new information because I believe it makes the problem clearer. You can always roll back to your earlier version if you find my edits inaccurate.

Comment: @ Joseph R. - Extremely grateful,It is a Perfect answer.

Comment: @binghenzq Thanks. I'm glad I could help :)