# Printf formatting with variable format - what does this var reference?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I am experimenting with printf formatting in bash and I ran across this piece of code:

```
#/bin/bash
divider===============================
divider=$divider$divider

header="\n %-15s %8s %10s %11s\n"
format=" %-15s %08d %10s %11.2f\n"
width=55

printf "$header" "ITEM NAME" "ITEM ID" "COLOR" "PRICE"

printf "%$width.${width}s\n" "$divider"

printf "$format" \
Triangle 13  red 20 \
Oval 204449 "dark blue" 65.656 \
Square 3145 orange .7
```

The line that I am interested in is the line that says:

```
printf "%$width.${width}s\n" "$divider"
```

What is that variable reference doing?  What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code `"%$width.${width}s\n"` generates a format string that is suitable for consumption by `printf`

In the script that you posted, `width` has been assigned the value `55`, so that both `$width` and `${width}` are expanded by bash to `55`: the entire first parameter to `printf` expands to `%55.55s\n`; this is the format `%s`, with a field width and precision specifiers that ask to print on exactly 55 characters. Given the value of variable `divider` at this point, this will simply print a line of 55 equal signs. A perhaps simpler way of printing the same thing would have been `perl -e 'print "=" x 55, "\n"'`.

The simplest form for the field width specifier is an integer: this asks `printf` to use at least this many characters for printing. If the corresponding parameter requires fewer characters than this to print, then the output is left-padded with spaces.

The simplest form for the precision specifier is a dot followed by an integer: when applied to `%s`, this sets the maximum number of characters to print. (It has a different meaning for numeric types.)

In response to a comment, I will also mention a little bit about shell variable expansion (the complete explanation can be found by searching for "parameter expansion" in the bash documentation, see also [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)):

- When a variable, say `x`, has been set, then `$x` expands to the value of `x`. If that value contains whitespace, then the expansion will be several words. This is why it's important in the code above that, for example, `"$format"` is within double quotes: this forces the expansion to be a single word (otherwise, `printf` would see a first parameter `%-15s`, followed by an argument `%8s`, etc., instead of receiving the entire format string as a single parameter).
- It is permissible to write `${x}` instead of just `$x` to expand the variable `x`; in the case above, `"${width}s"`, it is necessary to do so because if one had written `"$widths"`, then bash would try to get the value of variable `widths`, which is unset, resulting in an empty expansion.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  What I am understanding is this: `printf "%55s` and  `printf "%${width}"` is the same thing correct?  Using `"%$width.${width}s` tells printf to format the string with 50 chars padding and limit to 50 chars.  Is that correct?

Comment: also what I am having a hard time with is the use of brackets with the variable.  `printf ""%$widths"` generates an error but `printf "%${width}" ` does not.  But somehow `printf "%$width.${width}s\n"` works.  Can you tell me why or direct me to something that explains this?  I don't know the terminology to search for.

Comment: To respond to your first comment, `"%${width}s"` _expands_ to `"%55s"`. The format `"%50.50s"` would ask to pad to 50 characters and to print no more than 50 characters, so you are entirely correct on that part. To respond to your second comment, `$width` vs `${width}` is a matter of bash variable expansion; I will amend my answer to talk about it.

Comment: I see it now and thank you for the terminology.   It helps when you have an idea of what to ask Google to get the relevant results.