# Imagemagick having trouble escaping shell variables

Tags: shell-script, imagemagick, variable-substitution

I have an imagemagick command that is having trouble with the `$quote$arcangle` and `$halfdimension$quote` concatenated shell variables I'm passing as strings. Here's the transcript:

```
$> echo convert grad.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel Transparent -rotate 180 -distort Arc $quote$arcangle -90 $halfdimension$quote +repage -gravity center -crop $dimension"x"$dimension"+0+0" +repage h.png
   convert grad.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel Transparent -rotate 180 -distort Arc '360 -90 450' +repage -gravity center -crop 900x900+0+0 +repage h.png

$> convert grad.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel Transparent -rotate 180 -distort Arc $quote$arcangle -90 $halfdimension$quote +repage -gravity center -crop $dimension"x"$dimension"+0+0" +repage h.png
convert: unable to open image `-90': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: unable to open image `450'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

Yet, I paste in the output of the echoed command:

```
$> convert grad.png -alpha set -virtual-pixel Transparent -rotate 180 -distort Arc '360 -90 450' +repage -gravity center -crop 900x900+0+0 +repage h.png
(h.png is created without problems.)
```

Why is it not getting parsed correctly in the first instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work, write this to the file `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
arcangle=270
dimension=768
fin=grad.png
fout=h.png
convert $fin -alpha set -virtual-pixel Transparent -rotate 180 -distort Arc "$arcangle -90" +repage -gravity center -crop "${dimension}x${dimension}+0+0" +repage $fout
```

and `./foo.sh`

see also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4910/144337)

Comment: `"$arcangle -90"` <- that part did the trick. What was your logic behind omitting the outer radius argument?

Comment: See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc) , only arc_angle is mandatory