# Variable followed by underscore

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have files molecule416_out.pdbqt, where I am using variable **i** (molecule$i_out.pdbqt) to loop over all files. But it looks like it is reading the variable as **i_out** instead of just **i**. Since all those files are results of long simulations so can't rerun them to remove that underscore from out files. Is there any quick fix? Thanks.

Comment: Use `${i}_out....`

Comment: The answer below is good but also see [What is the best practice between using ${var} or $var? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288643) and the dupe it links to: [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899).  In short: always double-quote your variables and use `{}` when you need to separate a variable name from immediately adjacent text that happens to be valid characters for variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `molecule${i}_out.pdbqt`  The `${varname}` syntax delimits the part of the string that is the variable name, so the shell can do what you intend.