# Passing variables to script

Tags: bash, scripting

What is the difference between:

```
./script.sh "$VARIABLE"
```

and

```
./script.sh ${VARIABLE}
```

Is there any?

Comment: See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting or http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html. `${foo}` is the same as `$foo` and putting a variable inside double quotes (not necessarily just the variable) will prevent the variable from being split at certain characters like spaces (per default) or globbing to occur (e.g. `*` turning into a list of files).

Answer (score 1):

`$VARIABLE` and `${VARIABLE}` are effectively the same if they are standalone words. But notice the following example, especially in a script

```
VARIABLE=USER
echo $VARIABLE
```

you get output

```
USER
```

but when you type

```
echo $VARIABLE1
```

expecting to get

```
USER1
```

you get nothing as there is no variable as `VARIABLE1` defined

But if you use

```
echo ${VARIABLE}1
```

you get the expected `USER1` output.

Answer (score 0):

from Shawn J. Goff: [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

> VAR=$VAR1 is a simplified version of VAR=${VAR1}. There are things the
>   second can do that the first can't, for instance reference an array
>   index (not portable) or remove a substring (POSIX-portable). See the
>   More on variables section of the Bash Guide for Beginners and
>   Parameter Expansion in the POSIX spec.
>
> Using quotes around a variable as in rm -- "$VAR1" or rm -- "${VAR}"
>   is a good idea. This makes the contents of the variable an atomic
>   unit. If the variable value contains blanks (well, characters in the
>   $IFS special variable, blanks by default) or globbing characters and
>   you don't quote it, then each word is considered for filename
>   generation (globbing) whose expansion makes as many arguments to
>   whatever you're doing.

Comment: When you copy someone else's text, you need to [clearly mark it as having been copied by using quotation markup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). But don't copy someone else's answer on the same site, it's pointless: instead, [flag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question to [close](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Gilles: As provided from your link: When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange) make sure you do all of the following:

Provide a link to the original page or answer
Quote only the relevant portion
Provide the name of the original author

Comment: But when the questions are the same, don't do that. Instead, we have a mechanism for saying “this question is the same as another one so go and see the answers there”.