# Printing a Variable Which Contains $ Sign

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have a bash script which contains awscli as well. I am trying to print a variable which is created in a for loop. The variable that I am trying to print contains $ sign because of for loop. I couldn't print the value. Below I am sharing the script. The output of this script is only numbers which is generated in the for loop. I want to print the value which is generated in the command.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i counter=11
declare -i counter2=14

for i in {1..2}
do
    declare v1$i=$(aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors | awk -v counter1=$counter 'NR==counter1' | awk -F\" '{print $4}') 

    counter=$counter+7

    declare v2$i=$(aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors | awk -v counter3=$counter2 'NR==counter3' | awk -F\" '{print $4}')

    counter2=$counter2+7
    echo $v1$i
    echo $v2$i
done
```

Comment: Use `"${var}"` instead of just `$var`; `${x}${y}` instead of `$x$y`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote

Comment: I don't see any way that the braces would make a lick of difference there.

Comment: Kenneth, I tried your solution but result is the same. The output is:
taskscript.sh: line 16: ${v1$i}: bad substitution

Comment: @MichaelHomer I've performed several more tests; turns out that I was printing just `$y`, which was identical to `$x$y`. OP, my advice would be to use an array for v1 and v2 instead of v11/v12/v21/v22/etc.

Comment: If you're only outputting the result of the `awk` calls, why are you even trying to store it in variables?

Comment: Also, use `counter=$(( counter + 7 ))` to increment your counter.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the addition works since they're declared integer variables. Even `counter+=7` would do. Though I'm not sure if it would be more readable to just use `$(( .. ))` with regular variables ...

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead, that allows you to properly index the variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -ai counters=(11 14)        # indexes start from 0
v1=()
v2=()    

for i in {1..2}; do
    v1[$i]=$(aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors | awk -v counter1="$counter" 'NR==counter1' | awk -F\" '{print $4}') 
    counters[0]+=7

    v2[$i]=$(aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors | awk -v counter3="$counter2" 'NR==counter3' | awk -F\" '{print $4}')
    counters[1]+=7

    echo "${v1[$i]}"
    echo "${v2[$i]}"
done
```

You could probably put the `vN` assignments within another `for` loop to reduce the repetition.

Of course, if you're not using `v1` and `v2` for anything other than displaying the values once, you could just run  `aws ... | awk` directly and skip the variables and the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is supposed to accomplish but what it does is this:

In the first iteration - when i equals 1 - it declares variables v11 and v12 and assigns something to them and then prints $v1$i to the screen.

v1 is non-existent and $i is the value of i, so you should get 'nothing' with an appended 1 as output in the first loop:

And then in the second iteration - when i equals 2 - two times 2 for the same reason.

What you do after the equal sign with awk etc. is irrelevant for the outcome.

The suggestion to use an array and use $i as an index into it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to output the fourth `"`-delimited field on lines 11, 17, 18, and 21 of the output of an `aws` command.

```
aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors |
awk -F '"' 'NR == 11 || NR == 17 || NR == 18 || NR == 21 { print $4 }'
```

This calls `aws` once instead of four times, and calls `awk` once instead of eight times.

If you want this in an array:

```
readarray -t output < <(
aws iam get-group --group-name VideoEditors |
awk -F '"' 'NR == 11 || NR == 17 || NR == 18 || NR == 21 { print $4 }' )
```

The array `output` would now contain the data with one line from `awk` in each element, starting at index 0.

If you want to split that array into two, so that you get element 0 and 2 in one and 1 and 3 in the other:

```
v1=( "${output[0]}" "${output[2]}" )
v2=( "${output[1]}" "${output[3]}" )
```