# Difference ways to acces a variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am a beginner in Unix commands as I am currently studying how to write scripts. However, I can't understand how to actually access a variable.

Suppose I have a variable called name (`$name`), I see that sometimes people access it by using directly `$name`, while others use `${name}` or even `"$name"`. So this is very confusing, I am not sure what is the difference, as this is totally different from what I have learned in other programming languages.

Also, when I try to assign a string to a variable, do I write `$name="happy"`, `$name=happy`, `"$name=happy"` or let `"$name=happy"`.

Comment: See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between `$fred` and `${fred}`. The use of `{}` is needed if you need to say where the variable name ends. For example `echo ${end}ing` outputs the value of the `end` variable followed by the letters `ing` whilst `echo $ending` outputs the value of the `ending` variable.

The use of double quotes is to stop *word splitting*. As a rule of thumb every time you use a variable it should be in double quotes unless you **know** you want the result broken into words or you know that the values are ones which will never be split<sup>*</sup> (see also [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)).

As far as your examples for assigning are concerned, you probably don't want the `$` signs in any of them.

1. `name="happy"` - This is the thing you should use
2. `name=happy` - This works because "happy" is a single word, fine to use interactively but probably should be avoided in scripts
3. `"name=happy"` - Try to run a command with an unusual name of `name=happy`, almost certainly wrong.
4. `let "name=happy"` - runs a command called `let` which has its own rules, usually used for arithmetic in bash.

**Footnote**

* This is an over simplification but easy to remember. See [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for details of how commands are processed.

Comment: `$name=happy` as the question had it, would expand `$name` and then try to run `foo=happy` as a command, so it won't work as an assignment.

Comment: As a general rule, you use `$` to *get the value* of a variable, but not when *setting* it (as in `var="value"` or `read var`) or when getting/setting its properties (`export var` or `declare -p var`).