# How to use file in the loop as a input/output file in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

This is wrong:

```
for f in a*.dat; do 
    awk '.....' file1 "$f" > temp
    awk '.....' temp > "$f_out"
done
```

I would like to use a*.dat as input and then as output with suffix _out.
Many thanks

Comment: Related: [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_` is seen as a part of the variable name, so you are using the variable `f_out` in stead of `f` and append `out`. Using `{}` will solve your problem.

```
for f in a*.dat; do 
    awk '.....' "$f" > "${f}_out"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use curly-braces to disambiguate the variable `$f` from the remainder of the string (`_out`).

   i.e. `$f_out` refers to the variable named `f_out` (which probably doesn't exist, so evaluates to an empty string), while `${f}_out` means the value of variable `f` with `_out` appended.
2. Depending on what your awk scripts are doing, you probably, almost certainly,  don't need to run `awk` twice - it's almost never useful to pipe the output of an `awk` script into another `awk` script, and this:

   ```
   awk '.....' file1 "$f" > temp
   awk '.....' temp > "${f}_out"
   ```

   is effectively the same as this:

   ```
   awk '.....' file1 "$f" | awk '.....' > "${f}_out"
   ```

   and is better written as just:

   ```
   awk '{....}; {.....}' "$f" > "${f}_out"
   ```

   In a loop:

   ```
   for f in *.dat; do
     awk '{....}; {.....}' "$f" > "${f}_out"
   done
   ```

---

BTW, `awk` has a built-in variable called "FILENAME" which is equal to the filename of the file currently being processed.  Which means that you probably don't need the `for` loop, and can just do something like:

```
   awk '{....}; { .... }; { print > FILENAME "_out" }' a*.dat
```

Or just make sure that every print statement ends with  `> FILENAME "_out"`.

Without knowing exactly what the two `awk` scripts do, it's impossible to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

You command should be something like:

```
for f in a*.dat; do 
    awk '.....' "$f" > "${f}_out"
done
```

The output need to be on this way otherwise shell will try to interpret variable

```
f_out
```