# How to iterate through all the files (.war) and delete certain jar inside the .war

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Hi i need to delete all the log4j jars which is under webapps folder inside .war files recursively.
Say webapps/ has 10 .war files and it has .jar files i need to delete .jar from .war with a single command. I know how to delete jar inside war but I don't want to run 10 times to delete jar file.

```
> zip -d <SOME_FILE>.war <log4j>.jar
```

this deletes 1 log4j jar from .war need to perform on 10 war files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop.  e.g. something like this:

```
for f in webapps/*.war; do
  zip -d "$f" log4j.jar
done
```

Comment: ok thanks, so I used $f without quotes does it matter?

Comment: yes, it does.  if \*.war matches a filename with spaces, tabs, newlines, etc in it then it will break.  You may think "that's unlikely to happen because I know exactly what files are in that directory".  And that may even be true. However, you are developing a bad habit that **will** inevitably cause you serious problems one day.  Just get into the **good** habit of quoting your variables whenever you use them and avoid developing the bad habit.

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote) for some of the reasons why you should be careful about quoting and whitespace in shell scripts.