# How can I print two fields from a csv file to an output using bash-scripting, instead of one?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have not used bash often in the past for bash scripting & I am currently reading using bash scripting. The file contains a number of fields stored in csv format. The first scipt below will gather all the ips in a file; however, I am also trying to gather the **IP** and another field called **Network.**. Does anyone know I can achieve this?

```
files=`ls | grep data_batch_`
for file in ${files[@]}
do
  cat ${file} | cut -d , -f2 | grep -v "IP" > data_${file}
done
```

I have tried do add a boolean operator but I have no success. Also tried more pipes. I have not used bash often so I may be missing something with the syntax or not understanding why this is not a allowed?

```
    files=`ls | grep data_batch`
for file in ${files[@]}
do
  cat ${file} | cut -d , -f2 | cut -d, -f3 | grep -v "IP" && "Network" > data_${file}
done
```

For some reason when I do this, it appears to overwrite the **IP** value with the **NETWORK** value, instead of storing them both. Essentially, all I am trying to do is print two fields to a file instead of one, but I am not sure how to achieve his solution. Any tips will also help.

My desired output is the ip address value and the network value stored in the file. At the moment, all I get is the IP. The desired output below.

```
1.1.1.1
Network5
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Input file example?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous problems with your script:

```
files=`ls | grep data_batch_`
for file in ${files[@]}
do
  cat ${file} | cut -d , -f2 | grep -v "IP" > data_${file}
done
```

1. [Don't Parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)
2. Don't use backticks.  Use `$()` instead. It does the same thing but doesn't break quoting and can be nested.
3. You're using `files` in the `for` loop as if it's an array, but it's not an array.  You're defining it as a scalar string (the output of `ls | grep ...`).  If you want to define an array, you need to use parenthesis, e.g.

   This defines `files` as a string:

   ```
   $ files=$(echo 1 2 3)
   $ declare -p files
   declare -- files="1 2 3"
   ```

   While this defines it as an array:

   ```
   $ files=( $(echo 1 2 3) )
   $ declare -p files
   declare -a files=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
   ```

   Alternatively, you could use `mapfile` (AKA `readarray`):

   ```
    $ mapfile -t files < <(printf "%s\n" 1 2 3)
    $ declare -p files
    declare -a files=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
   ```
4. Double-quote your variable expansions.   Using curly-braces is **NOT** a substitute for quoting.   See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote) for reasons why.
5. In your second script, you are piping the output of `cut -d, -f2` into `cut -d, -f3`.  That's not going to work.

   The first `cut` only outputs one field (field 2).  The second `cut` will output exactly the same because there's only one field (or no fields, since there's no comma) in its input and you're telling it to output non-existent field 3.  Try running `echo 1,2,3 | cut -d, -f2` and then run `echo 1,2,3 | cut -d, -f2 | cut -d, -f3` and you'll see that the output for both commands is identical: `2`.

   To output two fields with `cut -f`, list them separated by commas.  For example:

   ```
   cut -d, -f2,3
   ```

   BTW, you can also specify a range of fields with `-`, e.g. if you wanted to output fields 2 to 5, you'd use: `cut -d, -f2-5`.   See `man cut`.
6. I don't know if this is a problem or not, but it's something to be aware of.  Your scripts are redirecting stdout to output files with the same name as the input file, but prefixed with `data_`.  So if your input file is `data_batch_1.csv` then your output file is going to be `data_data_batch_1.csv`.

   This may be exactly what you want, in which case it's not a problem - but it will mean that if you run the script again, the file glob will match both your original input files **and** the output files generated by the first run....resulting in filenames like `data_data_data_batch_1.csv`.   You may want to consider using a different naming convention for the output files, or write them to a different directory.

---

Anyway, those are the problems.  Here's a few solutions....try something more like this:

```
for file in *data_batch_*; do
  cut -d, -f2,3 "$file" | grep -v IP > "data_$file"
done
```

If you really wanted to use an array of filenames, you could use `mapfile` and `find` with `-print0`.  e.g.

```
mapfile -t -d '' files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*data_batch_*' -print0)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
   cut -d, -f2,3 "$file" | grep -v IP > "data_$file"
done
```

Alternatively, you could use `awk` instead of `cut`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$2$3 !~ /IP/ { print $2, $3 > "data_" FILENAME }' *data_batch_*
```

If neither `$2` nor `$3` contain "IP", then print them with stdout redirected to a file with the same name as the current filename (awk's `FILENAME` variable), prefixed with the string "data_".

This will be significantly faster because it doesn't have to fork `cut` and `grep` multiple times - once for every file it processes.

---

Finally, CSV files can (and often do) contain double-quoted string fields - and those quoted fields can contain commas.   Simple comma-delimited files without quotes and without commas embedded within fields can be processed reliably with `cut`.    Actual CSV with all its optional extras requires a CSV parser.  Your best option for this is to use either:

1. a language which already has a full-featured CSV parser - e.g. `perl` has the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module and `python` includes a [csv](https://docs.python.org/library/csv) library.
2. a tool like [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) or [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit)

Answer (score 1):

If you have awk available:

```
$ cat /tmp/abc
name1,0.0.0.0,NetworkName1
name2,0.4.2.3,NetworkName2
name3,0.1.43.5,NetworkName3

$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ;{printf $2","$3"\n"}' /tmp/abc
0.0.0.0,NetworkName1
0.4.2.3,NetworkName2
0.1.43.5,NetworkName3
```

so in this case,

```
for i in $(ls | grep -E ^test.*[.]csv$)
do
    cat $i | cut -d , -f2,3 >> testing.txt
done
```

can become

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ;{printf $2","$3"\n"}' test*.csv > testing.txt
```

If you do frequent structured text processing, investing some time in learning awk is going to be beneficial.

Comment: Wow, this is very useful command. Do you know if it's a way to add an conditional to this? For example, if I want to only output $3 if it is equal to a certain value?

Comment: yes,

$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ;{ if ($3=="something") {print $3;} else {printf $2","$3"\n";}}' test*.csv > testing.txt

you may want to have a look at https://books.google.se/books/about/sed_awk.html?id=Xu0G31e-4gIC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with the following:

Contents of directory:

```
$ ls
test.csv  test1.csv  test3csv test5.txt
```

where each of the files contains some lines like the following:

```
name1,0.0.0.0,NetworkName1
name2,0.4.2.3,NetworkName2
name3,0.1.43.5,NetworkName3
```

The script:

```
for i in $(ls | grep -E ^test.*[.]csv$)
do
    cat $i | cut -d , -f2,3 >> testing.txt
done
```

This takes all files that start with test, and end with `.csv`, cuts out fields two and three, and appends them to the file `testing.txt`.

The output file looks like this afterwards

```
0.0.0.0,NetworkName1
0.4.2.3,NetworkName2
0.1.43.5,NetworkName3
```

listing each IP address and each Network name on a separate line.

In your script, the reason that you see things in the output file being overwritten is because you are currently using the `>` operator, which overwrites everything in the file, while what you probably want is the `>>` operator, which appends the text to the end of the file.