# zsh: bad subscript for direct array assignment: 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, batch-jobs

I have the following bashscript below. My goal is to itterate over multiple files in the directory. The name of the files will be **batch_1, batch_2, batch_3, batch_4**, etc. There should be no more than 7 batches.

I have the following script below.

```
files=( $(echo 1) )
declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="batch_")
for data in ${files[@]}
do
  cat ${data} | cut -d , -f2,3 | grep -v "IP" > data_ip_${data}
done
```

However, when I run this I receive the error zsh: **bad subscript for direct array assignment: 0**

Does any know what can cause this specifically with my script? Or possible solutions? Any advice may help.

Comment: You're still not quoting your variable expansions, and still pointlessly using curly braces.  I explained why this is not a good idea in [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687556)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this with `bash`, or with `zsh`?  You've tagged this with bash, but your question mentions a zsh error.

- Like `ksh`, `bash` arrays start from zero.
- `zsh` arrays start from one (unless you have the `KSH_ARRAYS` variable set).   See `man zshparam` and search for `Array Subscripts`