# Exporting environment variable to user after login via su

Tags: environment-variables, su

I am struggling to work out what exactly the following alias does. I guess it is making the environment variable `COUNTER` available to the user `nobody` but the `COUNTER=${COUNTER}` preceding the ssh and the `SendEnv COUNTER` stump me. I have looked up the man pages but I am none the wiser.

```
COUNTER=280
...
alias run='COUNTER=${COUNTER} ssh nobody@localhost -o "SendEnv COUNTER"'
```

I'd like to rewrite this alias without ssh (because it has been disabled). Here is my attempt, but I am not sure if I have done the right thing if I don't understand what the original alias does exactly.

```
alias run='su - nobody -c "export COUNTER=${COUNTER}"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assigning a value to a variable on the same line / in the same statement before a program is run *temporarily* exports that variable to the environment for the program being run.   It's a way of exporting a variable for **just one program** - as soon as that program has been run, it's no longer in the environment and will not affect or be available to any subsequent programs.

   `COUNTER=${COUNTER} ssh ...` sets $COUNTER to itself, temporarily exports it to the environment, then runs `ssh`.

   It was probably written by someone who doesn't understand what curly braces or quoting are for because `COUNTER=$COUNTER` is 100% equivalent, and `COUNTER="$COUNTER"` would be even better, just because it's good practice to double-quote variables unless you are absolutely certain that you do not want to and know exactly why you do not want to in that particular case.  See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899)
2. `-o "SendEnv COUNTER"` is an `ssh` option that tells `ssh` what local environment variables should be sent to the remote server.  By default, only `TERM` is sent (and even then, only when a a pty is requested, e.g. an interactive ssh connection where you can type into the remote shell/program and see its output). From `man ssh_config`:

   > `SendEnv`
   >
   > Specifies what variables from the local `environ(7)` should be sent to the
   > server.  The server must also support it, and the server must be configured
   > to accept these environment variables.  Note that the `TERM` environment
   > variable is always sent whenever a pseudo-terminal is requested as it is
   > required by the protocol.  Refer to `AcceptEnv` in `sshd_config(5)` for how
   > to configure the server.  Variables are specified by name, which may contain
   > wildcard characters.  Multiple environment variables may be separated by
   > whitespace or spread across multiple `SendEnv` directives.
   >
   > See PATTERNS for more information on patterns.
   >
   > It is possible to clear previously set SendEnv variable names by prefixing
   > patterns with `-`. The default is not to send any environment variables.

   Note that the remote server can and will ignore any sent variables unless it is configured to accept them.  By default, it only accepts `TERM`.  From `man sshd_config`:

   > `AcceptEnv`
   >
   > Specifies what environment variables sent by the client will be copied into
   > the session's `environ(7)`.  See `SendEnv` and `SetEnv` in `ssh_config(5)`
   > for how to configure the client.  The `TERM` environment variable is always
   > accepted whenever the client requests a pseudo-terminal as it is required by
   > the protocol.
   >
   > Variables are specified by name, which may contain the wildcard characters
   > `*` and `?`. Multiple environment variables may be separated by
   > white‐space or spread across multiple AcceptEnv directives.  Be warned
   > that some environment variables could be used to bypass restricted user
   > environments.  For this reason, care should be taken in the use of this
   > directive.  The default is not to accept any environment variables.

   What this means is that, unless `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote server (actually `localhost` in your example, but that still qualifies as "remote"-ish enough for this purpose) is configured to accept the COUNTER variable, your `COUNTER=${COUNTER} ssh nobody@localhost -o "SendEnv COUNTER"` command wont do anything that just `ssh nobody@localhost` wouldn't do.
3. `su - nobody -c "export COUNTER=${COUNTER}` will run `export COUNTER=${COUNTER}` as user nobody, then exit (because the `-c` option tells `su` to run that command **instead of** just giving you a shell, it doesn't run it before giving you a shell).  Try `COUNTER="$COUNTER" su - nobody` instead.  Or just `export COUNTER` so that it is in the environment for all programs you run.