# Script to monitor directory size change

Tags: directory, nfs

I need a bash script to monitor directory size change.
The directory is a NFS file system with multiple users (500-600) who have sub-directories with vastly differing sizes.
E.G /home/nfs/xxx/ccc etc.
I need to be able to monitor, log and report for certain users that have directory sizes greater than e.g. 10GB or 20GB or indeed exceeded these sizes. This will need to be logged and the appropriate user sent a "friendly" email.
I do not want to use utilities and/or tools to do this, rather with a bash script.
This script would run on an ad-hoc basis.

Any help much appreciated.

MT

My efforts to date -

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -x
DISK="/cluster/vvvvvvv1/nfs-home/zzz" # Verzeichnis
CURRENT=$(df -h | grep ${DISK} | awk {'print $4'}) # get disk usage from monitored disk
MAX="70%" # max nn% disk usage
DOMAIN="naz.ch"


# Max Exceeded now find the largest offender
cd $DISK
for i in `ls` ; do du -sh $i ; done > /tmp/mail.1
sort -gk 1 /tmp/mail.1 | tail -1 | awk -F " " '{print $2}' > /tmp/mail.offender
OFFENDER=`cat /tmp/mail.offender`
echo $OFFENDER
du -sh $DISK/$OFFENDER > /tmp/mail.over70
mail -s "$HOSTNAME $DISK Alert!" "$OFFENDER@$DOMAIN"  < /tmp/mail.over70

# check if current disk usage is greater than or equal to max usage.
if [ ${CURRENT} ]; then
  if [ ${CURRENT%?} -ge ${MAX%?} ]; then
    # if it is greater than or equal to max usage we call our max_exceeded function and send mail
    echo "Max usage (${MAX}) exceeded. The /home disk usage is it at ${CURRENT}. Sending email."
     max_exceeded
  fi
fi

# init #
# main

#CLEANUP
```

Comment: This site is not a free script writing service. Post what you have researched, tried on your own and where you are stuck, then we will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a script person. I was merely asking for some assistance.

Comment: Nobody is born "a script person".

Comment: Very helpful of you.

Comment: I suggest you research the `quota` system. No need for scripts, complicated or otherwise.

Comment: I would prefer to accomplish all of this with just normal bash commands. No utilities/tools.

Comment: Why? Seriously why bother when the tools are already there for you? You just seem to be needlessly creating work for yourself. Those scripts are going to create unnecessary loading on the system.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. This "solution" requires that I use pure bash/Linux methods with no tools/utilities. I am a Mainframer and am not familiar with bash at all. I have no choice in the matter. Cannot be more specific.

Comment: I could accomplish similiar using REXX and assembler, alas I am not on a Mainframe at the moment.

Comment: My efforts to date:

Comment: @Teddy You should talk with the person who requires that the solution be pure `bash`, especially since you're using other tools like `du`, `sort`, and `awk`. Quotas are a standard tool and is the best solution for the job. Do you use assembler for every task on the mainframe or are you allowed to use other tools there?

Comment: Why don't you just enable user quotas on the NFS server?

Answer (score 0):

```
#assuming that your users are subfolders to same parent

disk=/home/disk # which contains users dirs user-{1..999}
limit='75%' 
current=$(df -k ${disk} | tail -1| awk '{print $5}')
max=10000000000 #in kilobytes (10G)

if [[ ${current//%/} -gt ${limit//%/} ]];then
    echo disk limit has been exceeded ${disk}
    # do your magick here
fi

find ${disk} -type f -exec du -k {} + | sort -nr | while read s f;do
    if test ${s} -gt ${max};then
        fsplt=(${f//\// }) # '/x/y/z' to 'x y z' as array
        echo "file size exceeded limits | user:${fsplt[2]} file:${f}";
        # do whatever here with file and user;
    else
        break; #cuz the list is sorted all remainning are smaller files
    fi
done

# you can customize find option to find only bigger than X size (optional)
```

Comment: Appreciate the input. I will give things a try and report back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws with your script, some of them quite serious:

1. **Never** parse the output of `ls`.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

   It wasn't even necessary, your "for i in `ls` ; do du -sh $i ; done > /tmp/mail.1" doesn't need a loop, and would have been better written as:

   ```
     du -sch */ > /tmp/mail.1
   ```

   or even:

   ```
    du -sch */ | sort -gk 1 | tail -n 1 > /tmp/mail.1
   ```
2. You should almost always double-quote your variable expansions (including shell parameters like `$1`, `$2`, etc)...while there are some circumstances where you might not want to do that (e.g. you actually *want* the shell's usual word-splitting to occur), that is exceptionally rare and usually the exact opposite of what you want and need to do.  In short: a good rule of thumb is "always quote unless you know exactly why you don't want to in this particular instance".

   See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766), [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899), [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).

   BTW, use double-quotes when you want variable interpolation to occur and single-quotes for fixed strings.  Double-quotes will expand any variables etc inside them. Single-quotes won't.  e.g. `'$foo'` is the literal string `$foo`, while `"$foo"` is the **contents** of a variable called `$foo`.
3. While it's not actually required, it is best practice to use all-lowercase or Mixed Case variable names for your own variables, just to ensure that they won't conflict with any environment variables used by the shell or other programs (which are almost always ALL-CAPS - e.g. the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable you're using - that's automatically sometime fairly early during the bootup process and exported to the environment so all child processes inherit it).
4. Since you're just trying to find the single "offender" using the most disk space (and how much space they're using), you don't even need to use a temporary file to do that.  You could just do something like this:

   ```
   disk="/cluster/vvvvvvv1/nfs-home/zzz"
   subject="$HOSTNAME $disk Alert!"
   domain='naz.ch'

   read -r size offender < <(du -sch */ | sort -gk 1 | tail -n 1 |
                               awk -F'[[:space:]]+|/' '{print $1, $2}')

   if [ -n "$offender" ] ; then
     cat <<__EOF__ | mail -s "$subject" "$offender@$domain"
       Your current disk usage is $size.  Please compress or delete
       any unnecessary files or directories.
   __EOF__
   fi
   ```

   But instead of doing this, you would be better off iterating over the output of `du -sch`, checking the size for each directory, and sending an email to the owner if it exceeds 10 or 20GB - the largest directory may be less than your 10-20GB limit.  Note that a directory's name isn't necessarily the same as the owner's username - it's common for a user's home dir to have the same name as the user but it isn't always the case.  **Don't** parse the output of `ls` to get a directory's owner - use `stat` instead.

   The above script fragment is just an example of how you could do this if you wanted to, it is certainly not a recommendation to actually do it this way.

---

BTW, you should probably be using the existing [quota](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxquota) tools rather than writing your own.  They not only have scripts to mail usage reports, they also allow you to set quota limits for each user and/or group which are enforced by the kernel.  If you're using Linux, these will almost certainly be available as package for your distro - e.g. on Debian, they're in the `quota` package so you can install them with `sudo apt-get install quota`.

There's a pretty good basic tutorial to installing and using `quota` at [Linux Quota - installation and configuration on Ubuntu and Debian](https://howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-quota-ubuntu-debian) - the installation method would be different for other distros (e.g. use `yum` or `dnf` on Fedora instead of `apt`) but configuration and usage would be the same.  Arch Linux's wiki also has a good tutorial at [Disk quota](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Disk_quota)

Quota should probably be installed and configured on your NFS file server, rather than on your NFS client machine.

Comment: Appreciate the hints, thank you. Still working on the problem. Will report back.