# Need help in running find command reading the file name from the for loop

Tags: linux, find

contents of `/tmp/fefile`

```
amx/eng/prf.amx
amx/eng/det.amx
bmb/menu.bmb
bmx/eng/menu.bmx
dll/tlnt.dll
dlx/eng/dlx
```

```bash
for file in `cat /tmp/fefile`
do
    if [ -f $file ]
    then
        echo "File '${file}' found in $(pwd) path."
        echo " Now i need to check if the  that file modified in last 10 mins with the below find command "
        find . -mmin -10 -type f -name ${file} -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(dir1|dir1|dir3|dir4)/.+" -printf "%P\n" > /tmp/base
        echo "The files that are modified recently are below"
        File=(cat /tmp/base)

        echo " now i am verifying that $file is matched with $File "
        if[ $file == $File ]
        then
            echo " tmp file matched with base file."
        else
            echo " file doesn't match"
        fi # Originally missing
    else
        echo "File '{file} not found."
    fi
done
```

Please help me  in correcting the above script in the find command to read the file name and check if it is modified in last 10 mins

if that file is modified and check if both files matched

Answer (score 1):

In the **find** command, you use a **regex**. This regex looks through the filenames listed in the **fefile** file and none of them match this regex. **NOTE: it looks in the filenames themselves, not inside the files**.

```bash
find . -mmin -10 -type f -name ${file} -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(dir1|dir1|dir3|dir4)/.+" -printf "%P\n" > /tmp/base
```

None of them have:

- `anything in any amount` PLUS
- `dir1` or `dir1` (again?! maybe dir2) or
  `dir3` or `dir4` PLUS
- `anything in any amount but at least one`

Another problem is the regex itself, it is:

```bash
".*/(dir1|dir1|dir3|dir4)/.+"
```

Maybe should be:

```bash
".*\/(dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4)\/.+"
```

You should escape the `/` with an `\`, as in: `\/`.

Also:

```bash
File=(cat /tmp/base)
```

Should be:

```bash
File=$(cat /tmp/base)
```

or

```bash
File=`cat /tmp/base`
```

Another point is the end of `find` line:

```bash
(...) -printf "%P\n" > /tmp/base
```

It's better change > to >>:

```bash
(...) -printf "%P\n" >> /tmp/base
```

Otherwise it will overwrite all files found and let just one.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your script fragment is that you are running find multiple times in a loop (once for each filename in `/tmp/fefile`).

This is extremely slow and inefficient because `find` is an *"expensive"* operation (recursing a directory tree with any tool is expensive in both time and disk I/O), not something you should run repeatedly in a loop unless you have no other choice (and there's almost always another, better choice).

It is much better to run `find` just once and process its output (e.g. with grep or awk or sed or whatever).

Try something more like this:

```
find ./dir[1234]/ -type f -mmin -10 -printf '%P\n' | grep -F -f /tmp/fefile
```

That will output a list of all files in dir1..dir4 that a) were modified in the last 10 minutes and b) match the fixed-string patterns in `/tmp/fefile`.

BTW, notice that this does not need a `/tmp/base` temporary file (also BTW, hard-coding tempfile names into a script is generally a bad idea, use `mktemp` or similar instead. I'd guess your `/tmp/fefile` should almost certainly not be hard-coded either, but I don't know what the rest of your script does or how this script fragment is executed)

You may need to tweak the `find` and/or `grep` options a bit to get exactly what you want - it took me a few minutes examining your script fragment to figure out what it is you're trying to do, and I'm still not 100% sure. I do know that you're using ~20 lines of shell code to very inefficiently do something that you could do much better and faster with either find alone or with find and grep (or some other common tool such as sed or awk or perl).

Note: this will not work correctly if any filenames contain newline characters.   You can use `\0` instead of `\n` in the `-printf` format string, along with GNU grep's `-z` option.

```
find ./dir[1234]/ -type f -mmin -10 -printf '%P\0' | grep -z -F -f /tmp/fefile
```

(to view the output in a terminal, you might want to convert the NUL separators to newlines, e.g. by piping the output to `tr '\0' '\n'`. This is fine for just displaying a list of filenames, but not safe if you need to do something with the filenames)

And, speaking of doing things with the filenames, one of the best and safest ways to do that is to store them in an array.  e.g. by using the bash built-in `mapfile` (AKA `readarray`) along with [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to populate an array with all the matching filenames.

```
declare -a found
mapfile -d '' -t found < <(find ./dir[1234]/ -type f -mmin -10 -printf '%P\0' |
                             grep -z -F -f /tmp/fefile)
```

`$found` will be an array containing all the matching filenames.  you can view the array with `declare -p found` (this is mostly useful for debugging purposes, to verify that the array contains what you think it should contain) or use it as args for a command, or in a loop, e.g.:

```
for f in "${found[@]}"; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

You can do anything else you want to do with `"$f"` in the loop, but remember to double-quote both the variable AND the array because they can contain any character except NUL.

Which reminds me, you use `${file}` in your `find` command, rather than `"$file"`.  This is a very commonly-made mistake: curly braces around variables are **NOT** a substitute for quoting.

They are used for parameter substitution (run `man bash` and search for the `Parameter Expansion` heading) and **to eliminate ambiguity when interpolating variable names in a string** (e.g. when you have a variable called `$foo` and you need to print it in a string immediately adjacent to a valid variable-name character - `echo "$food"` will output the value of $food, while `echo "${foo}d"` will output the value of $foo followed by a literal `d` character).

See [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899).

See also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766), [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Finally, since this question is about `find` and processing its output, and because you have been asking several find-related questions, see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).  And don't forget to read the related questions it links to.

Comment: Great answer! The OP using `-name ${file}` suggests though that they may want for `amx/eng/prf.amx` for instance to find a file called prf.amx in the eng subdir of an amx directory, and not any file whose path contain `amx/eng/prf.amx` (like `kabamx/eng/prf.amxil`), in which case it may be necessary to switch from `grep -zF` to `perl -0` and construct the appropriate regex.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's pretty much why i wrote the "You may need to tweak " paragraph.   And regardless of the exact details of what the OP wants to do, running find in a loop is pretty much guaranteed to be the wrong way to do it (by which I mean that I can't think of any valid reason to do that but there might be some extreme corner case where it might be appropriate. probably not, though).

Answer (score 0):

If the point is to find the regular files, last modified in the last 10 minutes whose last paths components are any of the strings that make up the lines of the `/tmp/fefile`, and whose path contains at least one directory component in the `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `dir4`, list, you can't do the matching by `-name`, that has to be done on the full `-path`.

`-path` (originally from BSD but now standard), and with some implementations `-wholename` (same as `-path`), `-ipath`, `-regex`, `-iregex` match on the whole path.

So some of the options are

- generate a `find` command line that uses a `-path` predicate for each line of `/tmp/fefile`:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . '(' -path '*/dir1/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir2/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir3/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir4/*' \
                  ')' '(' \
                      -path '*/amx/eng/prf.amx' -o \
                      -path '*/amx/eng/det.amx' -o \
                      ... \
                  ')' -type f -mmin -10
  ```

  which with bash you could do with:

  ```
  readarray -t args < <(
    </tmp/fefile LC_ALL=C sed '
  1!i\
  -o
  i\
  -path
  s|[*/?\\]|\\&|g; # escape glob operators
  s|.*|*/&|')
  LC_ALL=C find . '(' -path '*/dir1/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir2/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir3/*' -o \
                      -path '*/dir4/*' \
                  ')' '(' "${args[@]}" ')'
  ```

  (or `*/dir[1234]/*`, I'm assuming those are placeholders for some real directory names that can't easily by factorised in one pattern).
- leave the path matching to a post-processing command [as shown by @cas](/a/747993)
- Or since here your `find` implementation seems to be GNU `find` which  supports a `-regex` predicate, construct the regex dynamically:

  ```
  regex=".*/($(
    </tmp/fefile LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/[][$^*()+{}\\|.?]/\\&/g' |
    paste -sd '|' -))\$"
  LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended \
                  -regex '.*/(dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4)/.*' \
                  -regex "$regex" \
                  -type f -mmin -10
  ```

  (assuming `/tmp/fefile` is not empty).

Add some `-exec` predicate if you need to run commands on those files, or `-print0` (or `-printf '%P\0'` to strip the leading `./`) to pass the list NUL-delimited to some other command that can handle NUL-delimited list (a safe way to pass an arbitrary list of file paths).