# Piping xargs into GNU parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have the following script which gets the absolute paths of some directories and pipes them into GNU `parallel` for zipping. I keep getting a signal 13 error and I'm not sure why.

```
find $directory -maxdepth 1 | \
grep -v "^${directory}$" | \
xargs realpath | \
parallel -j 4 zip -r ${new_directory}/{/.}.zip {}
```

The error is `terminated with signal 13; aborting`. Sometimes the error is not raised but no zip file is present in the output, `new_directory`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first three lines of your script may be combined into `find "$(realpath "$directory")" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`. That way `realpath` is also only called once.

Comment: @FelixJN I think he wants to run the realpath for each one of the files, not just for the top directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting to the actual failure that you're having, there are few things you need to fix in your command to handle some corner cases

```
find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | \
xargs -0 realpath | \
parallel -j 4 zip -r "$new_directory"/{/.}.zip {}
```

The changes in `find` are:

- `-mindepth 1` - this will exclude your top directory, so you won't need your `grep -v` command.
- `-print0` - This will solve a possible problem case any of you files include spaces or any escape characters. All the files will be delimited by the the null character instead of a new line.

That's why you also need to add the `-0` to your `xargs` command, so it would read the input delimited by the null characters.

#### Further troubleshooting

In case it doesn't solve your issue, you'll need to debug it further.

1. First, remove the `parallel` command altogether and check if the input for this command looks as expected.
2. If it seems ok, add verbosity to the `parallel` command to capture exactly what it's doing:

```
parallel -t -j 4 zip -r ${new_directory}/{/.}.zip {} 2> parallel.log
```

- Then you'll have the list of commands it's running in the `parallel.log` file. Check if the `zip` commands seem to be generated correctly.

3. If you still don't see anything unusual at the list of `zip` commands in the log file, try the commands in the file:

```
bash -x parallel.log
```

At some during the process you'll have to see at what stage you receive the error.

Comment: +1. You can eliminate the pipe to `xargs` by replacing the `-print0` with `-exec realpath -z {} +`.   realpath's `-z` option tells it to produce NUL-separated output. Also, both `$directory` and `$new_directory` need to be double-quoted, and there's no need for the curly braces around $new_directory (see [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899)).  Finally, GNU `parallel` needs a `-0` or `--null` option for NUL separated input.

Comment: All together, that's `find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec realpath -z {} + | parallel -0 -t -j 4 zip -r "$new_directory"/{/.}.zip {} 2> parallel.log`

Comment: @cas, if the number of files in the directory is relatively small, I prefer using `xargs`, because then `realpath` will run once for all the files at once instead of for each file. If there are many files and the `parallel` command will need to wait until all the files are found, it might be better to add `-n` (max-args) to `xargs` with some reasonable number.

Comment: Using `+` instead of `\;` to terminate the `-exec` causes `find` to fit as many filename args into the command line as it can - just like `xargs`.    xargs is useful when you're not using find (i.e. when you have something else generating your list of arguments, e.g. when the args aren't filenames), but when you're using find, it's redundant...-exec is better, find's own built-in xargs.   BTW, parallel has its own `-N` option for max args, similar to xargs'  `-n` option.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you're going to use xargs anyway, xargs has a `-P` / `--max-procs` option for parallel execution.  It's not as flexible as parallel, but it is much simpler to use and should be good enough for zipping some directories.   IMO & IME, a task like that isn't well suited to parallel execution, anyway, because it's a mostly I/O-bound job (especially on any modernish CPU, say <= 20 years old)...and running zip multiple times in parallel is just going to make that worse, with each of the jobs contending with each other for read and write disk I/O.